# What is the record for the most downvoted post on SO?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

I see a question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563929/i-need-help-do-you-want-to-participate-creating-the-best-os-ever#

Last check it was on -17 and falling fast.  It's already been closed and no doubt will be sent to the bin shortly, but it got me thinking.  What is the lowest score achieved on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: It doesn't really, it was curiosity.  Looks like my question may end up the same way :/

Comment: @intracept good thing Meta questions don't actually cost reputation, huh `;)`

Comment: Kinda ironic how this post has 36 downvotes

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on [this Stack Exchange Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/12223/lowest-voted-posts), it appears to be

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734

The other posts in that query are election posts.

Comment: Wow.  That is impressive.  Sorry, I didn't realise there was a way of searching for that.

Comment: More impressive is the Reversal Badge earned by the person who answered the question.

Comment: Indeed.  I see the linked question above has now been deleted.  It was at -25 the last I saw.  Not even a contender! :)

Comment: @intracept the post that Robert linked to actually has 218 downvotes, with 71 upvotes to bring it to its current score.

Comment: Wasn't that question closed for emotional reasons? I consider it perfectly legit. It's either possible or not possible to send 100 000 mails/week in PHP. If it's possible then solution can be provided.

Comment: @VotetoClose I see dozens of questions which are more broad than that one and TBH this is not wrong, because usually question must be broad to some extent to be interesting. Paradox is that close reasons are totally subjective and you can always say that question is too broad. And if it's up to library asker asks "is there", not "which library is the best". Such questions were O.K. in the past, but maybe it has changed cause SO becomes more and more restrictive. I wish it will not destroy this site, but I'm becoming tired with this + seeing questions incorrectly marked as duplicates etc.

Comment: @doc: It's not about legalities.  Most of the downvotes on that question are there because the OP had the hubris to ask "how can I become a spammer?"

Answer (score 6):

Based on this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=score%3A-1000..-147), this post is **now** the lowest scored thing on Stack Overflow at -149 (As of 7.9.2020). A lower score than the one given by the current accepted answer to this question.

> [Accepted Answer to: Fixing 'Lock Wait Timeout Exceeded'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766785/fixing-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-try-restarting-transaction-for-a-stuck-my/4797328#4797328)

And it probably will stay this way for a while. The 2nd lowest score is [-146](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734), but it is on a locked Q and cannot be voted on. The third lowest score is [-110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384565/return-json-object-with-duplicate-keys-using-c-sharp?r=SearchResults&s=17%7C0.0000) which is significantly higher.

Answer (score 1):

This one has `-3200` as of today :

> [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story)

Comment: The question is asking for the lowest-ranked question on the main SO site, not Meta. I don't doubt, however, that that's probably the most-downvoted question on the entire network, or at least in the top 5.