# Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, announcement, stack-overflow-talent

**TL;DR** – On March 31, 2022, we will discontinue Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story. This includes all job listings, saved searches, applications, messages, recommended job matches, job ads, developer story, saved resumes, and the salary calculator.

---

Back in April 2021, [Prashanth posted an update](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/04/07/an-update-on-our-product-led-saas-transformation/) on the transformation of our company and he provided a high-level overview of the changes planned for our Talent business:

> *We are realigning the Talent business to focus more on customer employer branding and company awareness needs, and moving away from job slots and direct hiring. This will tie the product closer to what we offer through Stack Overflow Advertising [...]*

[Some of you wondered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406651/1328704) what practical changes this shift in strategy would bring about. In the months that followed, we realigned our internal teams and mapped out the plan to transform our Talent & Advertising businesses.

### Why?

Before going into specific changes, I want to take a moment to talk about why we decided to transform these businesses and products. As we considered the next stage of growth for us as a company, we went back to product fundamentals and asked ourselves: how can we leverage our unique position to solve real, meaningful problems for our users and customers?

While Talent & Jobs helped us get to where we are over the past decade, the talent acquisition space is not one where we have a strong competitive advantage. Developers, as you all know, don’t have a hard time finding job opportunities. The problem is often finding the *right* opportunity and job boards and sourcing are ineffective solutions. The effort it would take us to truly differentiate in this space is not one we could justify.

Exiting this space allows us to refocus on products that build on our core strengths: knowledge reuse and building communities at scale.

### What changes are we making?

The following features will be discontinued and removed from the site by March 31, 2022:

- Jobs – including job search, saved searches, applications, messages, recommended job matches, and job ads
- Developer Story and any saved resumes
- Salary Calculator
- All emails, settings, and data associated with these features
- All employer-facing features related to Jobs and Developer Story

### What can you expect in the coming months?

- Late January 2022 – users will no longer be able to create new Developer Stories
- February 2022 – users will start to see banners and notices on all deprecated features
- February 2022 – the Salary calculator will no longer be available
- Early March 2022 – users will be able to easily export all their data related to Jobs & Developer Story
- March 31, 2022 – all remaining discontinued features will be removed from the site

### What are we continuing to support?

The Advertising components of our Talent offering, specifically focused on Employer Branding.

Developers and technologists often want to learn about companies as they begin to evaluate opportunities in order to understand things like the company culture, the work/life balance, the social and environmental policies, the tech stack, and the learning and development opportunities companies offer. This is collectively referred to as “Employer Branding.”

[Academy to Innovate HR (AIHR)](https://www.aihr.com/blog/employer-branding-strategy/) provides a more detailed explanation of employer branding and how companies think of it as part of their talent strategy. Companies can continue to use Stack Overflow’s Employer Branding solutions to promote their employer brand through company pages and other types of advertising.

---

Jobs & Talent have been a part of Stack Overflow in some form for almost 12 years and have played a critical role in getting us to this stage as a company. In fact, it was also the first product I worked on when I joined Stack Overflow 5 years ago as a Product Manager. To those of you who have used Jobs or created a Developer Story, on behalf of everyone who has worked on Jobs & Talent over the years, I’d like to thank you for trusting us to be a part of your job search process.

The decision to sunset these products wasn’t a simple one and we understand that this may have an impact on your job search process. If you have any questions or concerns, please let us know by posting them as answers to this question.

Comment: I really like the Joel Test and the overall layout of SO Jobs. IMO it'll be sad to see it go.

Comment: I'm sad to see SO Jobs go. It was one of my favorite places to search and apply to jobs. The application experience felt more consistent between jobs than other sites.

Comment: I'm really sad to see the salary calculator go. It was a good way of verifying (along with other sources like glassdoor) that I really was being underpaid in one case, and helped me understand what salary to expect when moving to a new city in another. I suggest it to coworkers all the time.

Comment: It was never accurate outside of a few bubbles.

Comment: This outright sucks! I got a job from my SO resume. And it's cool to send a link to my resume that is interactive with SO when applying for a job.  Plus with jobs posted to SO, you had less chance of it being recruiter spam.

Comment: I'm really disappointed in this. I've always found SO _much_ better than other job sites for finding quality positions.

Comment: It's one thing to remove SO jobs, but why remove the salary calculator?

Comment: I don't use a resume/CV any more, I send people my SO Dev story! You're not asking, you're telling me you will cut off my left arm... Thats what this feels like anyway. While I understand removing the jobs side of things, Dev story adds value to our SO account by giving us a space to publicly broadcast our endeavours, Dev Story increases long term SO user retention. If users move their personal career profile to another platform they will spend less time on SO and then less time in review and other mod queues.

Comment: I have no idea what "*employer branding*" is about. Can you be more specific please what "*company pages and other types of advertising*" refers to? Is a "company page" the company description part of jobs, just now without position offerings?

Comment: Feature request: can we now finally get rid of the cringe-worthy site title: "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share & Build Careers"?  How about "where developers compile, link & build binaries" :)

Comment: Does this mean the Pluralsight IQ Skill integration will go as well?

Comment: As someone who recently found a job through SO Jobs the SO Jobs was light years ahead of many other places, although I believe it could certainly have used a few improvements it's really sad to see it go. I loved that I could filter and find jobs that are actually relevant to me without having to sift through 35345 other job postings that just happened to contain a keyword or something like many other jobs websites do, I'm really disappointed in this.

Comment: Agreed, @ChrisSchaller! It's one thing to remove Jobs, but why remove the Developer Story? I like keeping all my developer projects in the Story, and it will definitely be nice later on when I'm applying for jobs. I guess I'll have to export it and put it somewhere else (sigh)... am I the only one, or does it seem like everything changes for the worse these days? Maybe I'm just pessimistic....

Comment: Bye bye /jobs, we had some fun times building ya <3

Comment: Seems like a bad decision. Can't imagine it costs much to leave it in place. I'd believe its costs are more than it's benefits to the company if you'd laid out some cost/revenue numbers.

Comment: Yet another case of destroying something that works and helped many people, and converting it to a useless feature. Good job! keep it going

Comment: "...users will be able to easily export all their data related to Jobs & Developer Story..." Shouldn't this already have been a feature? That would have probably set these products apart. Oh well.

Comment: "The problem is often finding the right opportunity" -- not to be mean or anything but I am disappointed that SO is punting on this topic. "This is collectively referred to as 'Employer Branding.'" -- isn't this a conflict of interest? It's often the stuff that goes *unsaid*, that an employer is ashamed of, that makes it a "not right" opportunity. e.g., is their org so stiff that you need an act of Congress to get any kind of collaboration? Is their product/project management well thought out (target audiences, etc.)? Do their executives even respect software as a profession?

Comment: While I never used this feature, I know it was well-loved by many. Seems like an odd decision to sunset it when there isn't a replacement ready to go. Especially since this is (was?) one of the main revenue streams for the company.

Comment: my issue with it was there was always such a large number of smaller businesses that never used it. Was it due to lack of discoverability by smaller businesses? cost? For us it was cost. Just priced right out of the equation, even though there were no other businesses in the area advertising. I wanted SO jobs to work, but it never worked for us,

Comment: This is sad. Bye bye, jobs. ☹️

Comment: Terrible news. SO Jobs was at the very top of my list of reputable job lists. And Dev Story landed me some of the best interviews

Very sad news!

Comment: ouch...Add me to the list of folks who got a job via SO Jobs.  IMO this is a mistake.

Comment: I feel a certain prestige by having my developer story on SO. It conveys a sense of accomplishment in a way that a resume or a portfolio on a site that's non-industry specific does not (i.e., "Top 5% in <topic>"). It's also worth noting that I'm here commenting because today I went to SO jobs to browse through jobs.

Comment: "not one where we have a strong competitive advantage" - this is 100% false. SO Jobs & Developer Story are so much better than any other job listing site. "The effort it would take us to truly differentiate" ... but you already have differentiated yourself! I don't understand this decision at all.

Comment: The "Why" is not seriously satisfying. The plan could be optimization of them, not removing. I believe it is closer to a mistake or a backward. While exactly the removed items make the solutions more realistic here.

Comment: This is a rare miss for stack overflow. One of the reasons that I spend time answering questions is because employers can see that I am in the top x% on a certain technology on my developer profile. Please reconsider this change!

Comment: For what it's worth, if you kept just the "Jobs" ad bar on the right of the page and targeted based on tags, it would probably be worth doing!  A lot lighter weight, would be cheaper for advertisers, etc.  Let us buy an ad for some reasonable fee, in a self-service way.

Comment: Feeling very sad after reading this post.SO helped to get job offers from where any other job portal couldn't get. I don't know what to do now. Not a kind of news to hear in the start of the day. very very very very very sad!!. I hope SO rethinks on this.

Comment: As a student of Electrical Engineering, I have only the opportunity to submit my resume in SO Jobs. Feeling bed to see you go SO Jobs! Thanks for everything

Comment: It's not hard to find a job or project, but finding a solution to a weird or difficult error or even how to implement a really hard feature that works best thanks to you

Comment: At least teach LinkedIn how to create a nice job search with useful filters before you deprecate this!

Comment: And what is next, shutting down StackOverflow? Why would you shut down a product that everyone loves? Is it not generating enough revenues? Do you need donations? You can keep it running along with your Employer Branding and stuff.

Comment: Since StackOverflow Jobs is apparently inferior to other jobs portals, what are the actually good jobs portals? I thought SO *was* the good portal, but apparently I'm missing out.

Comment: Keep destroying what we love to concentrate on adds and "jobs"(Money), exactly what most of your users do not care about at all. One day a decentralised SO will emerge and your monopoly will be over.

Comment: What a shame. I got my current great role through Jobs. I hope you reconsider if it's not too late.

Comment: soo sad, but if i may ask, will there be any other platform where one can go to access jobs primarily targeted towards start over flow....

Comment: Alternatives? I don't know where else to look...

Comment: Worst decision. All the cool & great features you guys are dropping collectively. Again hands down from my side. Shame!

Comment: Very disheartening to see the jobs go, SO is specifically focused on programming jobs, hiring managers can take a look at the candidate's SO profile to get an idea of their communication/developments skills from their SO posts and this job board had some filters which none of the other job boards have. I think these are enough competitive advantages to continuing the job board.

Comment: The `Jobs` section is a gem of a feature imho. I will miss it, but times change I guess.

Comment: You still _can_ show this, @h-sifat, even without Developer Story ;-) , but I'd like it to stay as well.

Comment: Sad to see it go. I find it the best jobs board out there

Comment: I guess you were losing money on this?  Somehow?  For the life of me, though, I can't imagine _how_.  That seems like an an impressive achievement in itself.  Bravo!

Comment: Since joining SO 10 years ago, and eventually discovering the resume -> now dev story, I was all for it. I ported my CV from LinkedIn and never looked back. I'm super unhappy about this news of removing it... to this day I still link back to my dev story on here, or send it to anyone who might be interesting in working with me. Please don't remove it :(

Comment: Is there anything we could do as users to stop this from happening?

Comment: This came a bit late. S.O. settled as data repository a while ago, nothing new here. Obviously, highlighting employer branding makes more money than highlighting programmer nobodies. Collectives was the first step, this is the next.

Comment: The salary calculator was a really neat feature, sad to see it go. Good thing, that more and more job boards require salary brackets, like: https://devitjobs.us
 https://germantechjobs.de or https://nofluffjobs.com Also, the Joel Test was a nice add-on to have an overview of the company's engineering philosophy.

Comment: This is sad news indeed, as SO Jobs is definitely the best in the IT market; especially with its unique search features like "relocation support" & "visa sponsorship". I wish this continued maybe as a seperate product or site with a seperate team to keep making a difference in the market.

Comment: I downvoted this question-notice because I cannot feel it has clear explanaton on why this decission. And, after reading the long list of arguing answers, I see I'm not alone.

Comment: Lots of resumes/portfolios are based on developer story, doesn't make sense to remove it. It's always nice to see the achievements/awards/career/etc... of the contributor. they are not robots :)

Comment: I'm sad to see Jobs section go. It was one of my favorite places to search and apply to jobs. Stack overflow is open area where recruiters could map true potential of candidates.

Comment: People don't seem to get that this is an _announcement_, not a _discussion_, even though it's tagged with discussion, because meta tags are mandatory. Jobs is EOL. Asking for it to stay is asking for water to stop being wet. You got the news, now go out there and find an alternative, there are _plenty_. Never bet on a single horse.

Comment: This will be a bad decision, letting go of Developer story is a disaster. It is a cool feature that everyone loves. It will be a justice to the community if you don't kill the 'Developer Story'

Comment: Just another notch on the belt of tightening cost at the expense of the community. Have to inflate that net revenue if the company is to be sold in the next few years. Expect more features to be dropped and a shrink in the workforce. Growing companies expand... sinking ones throw things overboard.

Comment: Developer story was a cool feature. sad to know you're dropping it.

Comment: That is SO disappointing.  I liked looking for jobs here more than anywhere else, partly because of that wonderful Joel test rating, and so many had salaries listed.  I sure wish you would reconsider, it was one of the best parts of stack overflow imo

Comment: This may not be the best place to ask, but what does *customer employer branding* even mean? Internet searches only yield the linked blog post and excerpts from random buzzword collections.

Comment: I also agree with @ChrisSchaller and everyone else who would be sorry to see the Developer Story disappear. If you're going to remove Jobs, please _don't_ also remove the **Developer Story**. It's an asset unique to Stack Overflow, - no other historical career profile on the web can match it for detailing contextual expertise.

Comment: "Competition". Only this word nowadays... We'll see where this leads us, but as a comparison, it f***** the french electricity market for customers. Sometimes, you should ask yourself if your goal is always and only to make money, or to do something nice for people. I think I start to understand what SO's position is. (Here come the people saying "it's a business, it's here to make money". Yes yes, money, always money...)

Comment: this is not good that you're discontinuing jobs and all, it's really easy to find companies and available jobs and we can directly apply from here.

Comment: Something is very wrong with stackoverflow.. change after change it is gradually becoming a place I cannot love anymore like I used to.

Comment: the Q&A, jobs and develoepr story can exists togheter because all of them connect people in some way, **connection** is important for the community

Comment: Stack overflow jobs is a really good space.. I haven't even had enough time using it and before that it's leaving. I believe SO can definitely create a creative job space and it doesn't need to go :(

Comment: I've been using SO as my online resume for years. I don't know if there is any way we can prevent this decision.

Comment: Which survey results indicated that developers want fewer opportunities and more HR branding channels?

Comment: Under the Why? Section I read: "...the talent acquisition space is not one where we have a strong competitive advantage..." But according to what? I've just started using SO again and I was really impressed with the Job listing portion and how relevant it actually is to one's skillset. IMO that's a very strong competitive advantage.

Comment: It feels like, "purchased by Microsoft == quality gets flushed".  Unfortunate.

Comment: There is no better place to look for *good* software development jobs. The SO jobs feature lets me filter and look specifically for jobs using new and interesting technologies. Not only that, but imo the quality of job postings themselves on SO is superior to other job sites I'm guessing because they're less likely to be written and/or misedited by someone who doesn't understand the content of the job posting. The jobs feature already has a competitive edge at least from the perspective of a job seeker. It is a shame to see it go.

Comment: Wait, did the CEO say that the most visited site by software engineers has no competitive advantage on posting jobs for software engineers? Wow.  There is something else going on.

Comment: Just would like to say that anything related to Jobs on SO is the main reason I started answering questions and sharing my knowledge on this site. Taking it away takes away that motivating factor.

Comment: What does customer employer branding even mean? My take is that SO will stop working for developers and will start to work for companies. But they are forgetting that developers built this site by sharing their knowledge.

Comment: What a terrible decision.  I got my longest tenure job through Careers and use it as my online CV.  There's really no good alternative.  I think you could have pivoted it rather than destroying this resource.

Comment: This is only comparable to YouTube removing the dislike count. Makes you wonder about how management decision are made and how disconnected people in companies get about what people thinks / expects from their product(s)

Comment: How could you possibly think that this is a good idea? I'm agog. Was it not making enough money? I have nothing kind to say about this.

Comment: I dont know. I always thought that jobs opportunities had its space here. I was not like unsolicited advertising like on ANY OTHER web on the internet. But what I am wondering the most, how is it possible that they can not afford do both: work on the community and also jobs/HR 2.0... I think it is step back. But OK. Big ballsy step anyway...

Comment: Even though I am in the top 5% for a technology on Stackoverflow via answers, I didn't get any new opportunities or pay rises because of it. Maybe this is because to get noticed you need to be in the 0.1%? But whatever the reason, at the end of the day, I found SO jobs ineffective for growing my career, and the investment I made answering questions here a waste of time. So I'm not sad to see it go, and I don't care about contributing answers here anymore since there's no return on that investment.

Comment: No-one seems to have mentioned (I think) what I saw as the benefit of Developer Story when I filled mine in, giving question readers the ability to see the angle the asker was coming from. That's nothing to do with Jobs at all.

Comment: Actually I do not think this is going to be a good idea. Hope that the company could reconsider this decision

Comment: In short: more money from company ads! Devs don't need us, companies do! More seriously, this is not just a feature removal, this is a major vision shift from developers to a cosmetic front for companies.

Comment: TL;DR; Totally  Disappointed, What kind of product fundamental is into it.  Job recommendation in SO are clutter free  and I recommend lot of my friends to use SO to apply for the Job.  This Job and Developer section attracting the people and act as a catalyst to contribute in SO community.
I am totally disappointed by this move.

Comment: This shows the business-first approach. No matter what people loved.

Comment: Developer story were much better then LinkedIn. You could sell it least to some other compony to support. It was very good.

Comment: I have been employed a few times via this exact thing you are killing. I am not sorry I hoped away from SO some time ago. A perfect example how greed ( imho ) will kill a magic platform. Stupidity at its finest, to me.

Comment: The whole point for many devs to collaborate and reply to questions is to gain reputation to attract employers

Comment: You may remove the whole job part but why don't you let developers keep there stories? We used our time to populate that.

Comment: I guess they no longer care, because "Stack Overflow acquired by Prosus for $1.8 billion"

Comment: Negative voting to this question means (as SO puts it) "not enough research effort" has been put into it. Could this be the case? If the customer is not happy, you should look better into that...just saying

Comment: ...and putting this here to get a gold medal is totally cheating IMO xD that first gold medal doesn't count @Puneet Mulchandani :-P

Comment: This is sad, SO Jobs was mt #1 place to look for openings, I also found my first job through SO Jobs and it was an awesome one.

Comment: Are we still in 1997 and hosting does cost signifikant money?

I mean this stuff has literally 0 costs, once its implemented. I really dont get SO course here....

Comment: I cannot believe this is anything but money-motivated. You're taking away a unique, great experience, relevant addition to the site that already works. So much for SO being a community. 

Please reconsider.

Comment: i've had numerous compliments about my CV being clean and to the point.   Which for a long time, has been a PDF export of my developer story!  You could leave the tools that benefit developers - salary calculator, dev story etc.  Just because there is no direct revenue stream, doesn't mean they don't hold value.  As is sometimes the case - the users are being overlooked

Comment: I hate LinkedIn and I left it few months ago because it got annoyed by the amount of non senses posts in my feed about politcs, dieaseases and everything else but carreer related. The only platform I was using for looking for jobs was stackoverflow. That is very sad!

Comment: Please review your decision and let developer story and jobs board go  In the days of having every other person on LinkedIn claiming to be a leader, entrepreneur, inventor etc, stackoverflow allows me to stand out without having to brag about my knowledge. I can answer questions here and people visiting my user page would know I am top x% in the said technology. To me, developer profile in SO is way more effective than those profiles you find in LinkedIn or other professional social networking sites.

Comment: Where can I find a list of pages/sites that is linking to my SO cv so I can be sure to not miss any location?

Comment: This is pretty sad. I managed to get a new job via Stakoverflow jobs and we were also hiring via Stackoverflow jobs. I think it was a well-done and well-trusted source of talents :(

Comment: It's better to consider keeping at least the Skill IQ section.

Comment: First they stopped support for a mobile App, not they're dropping the jobs part of the site. Call me cynical, but I think we are seeing the rapid decline of SE.  I don't think the resources from the App/Jobs will be put into improving the site. Instead, it seems the top folks at SE seem to be cutting away everything for some reason. Whats next, removing the ability to ask a Question?

Comment: What the heck is "customer employer branding"? It doesn't sound like something a developer would benefit from. Same for "Company awareness needs".

Comment: I use Stack Overflow every day and this is the first I've heard of it.  Can we maybe un-make the difficult decision to sunset jobs? The reason, "The effort it would take us to truly differentiate in this space is not one we could justify." makes no sense.  I don't believe that's the real reason.  Just having the board exist here makes it truly different.  I've used it many times.  Was SO somehow losing money by keeping the jobs board? I guess that would be a reason to kill it I can't argue with.  Don't lie to us.

Comment: This decision will affect lots of people who answer questions to raise their profile. I always thought SO Jobs board offer better opportunities than others. Reconsidering this decision might be in the interest of SO to be in the right side of things.

Comment: While this is a bummer, I sometimes forget that StackOverflow is a business—not a charity—that has its own prerogatives and goals, and must take care of itself. Thanks for all the services through the years, for which I've never paid a dime. I wouldn't be the same developer without this platform.

Comment: SO Jobs was already positively differentiated from -- and better than -- most other job boards I've seen. Volume is smaller because it's relatively focused and not spammy. I do not believe SO couldn't comfortably allocate resources to keep these features running well, that makes no sense. This smells of laziness and mundane internal greed, same as most bad business decisions.

Comment: This is a shame.  While it's true that it's easy to find developer "jobs" other places, the SO Jobs board has been my source for quality and interesting job ads for quite some time, and also how I've advertised myself and my credentials as a developer.  Very, very sad to see this change.

Comment: Jobs on SO are 100 times better than any other platforms. I just don't use it becasue I'm not looking for a job but next time when I would need a Job I'm sure I'll  miss SO's Jobs, it is very developer friendly and its clean will be greatly missed. I wish you guys spin it as a separate product/company

Comment: It's really sad how SO ignored all the opinions from Developers about this topic =/

Comment: I don't get why you don't see the value in making these features better. It's already half-backed and all you need to do is add new features to it to become even better. You already own part of the market. This is a very big setback for StackOverflow and very bad news for all of us. I see it as a lack of vision :-( Why not just make it a new platform called "StackJobs" and let the community take care of it. Later when your product vision manager gets fired you can start investing in it and make it the one-stop for great jobs again.

Comment: That's too bad about the job board.  SO probably has the best tech-stack filtering I've seen for job postings.

Comment: If you can't make enough $ off the jobs, then what's the point of having it I suppose from a business perspective. The dev story is really just your profile, but with a weird timeline, so I don't think you'll get many arguments there.

Comment: This is a really misguided decision. I speak as both a software developer and a hiring manager. SO is uniquely positioned to provide a superior job search experience for both sides. We use the other products on the market because we have to, not because they're better. Put some money into marketing the service to employers instead of just killing the whole module.

Comment: What a stupid misguided decision. Sounds like SO is trying to give the competition a leg up.

Comment: Anytime something good comes along it's only a matter of time before corporate interest come along and ruin it. A company built entirely knowledge and expertise of it's community. I really hope this is just one stupid decision and not the beginning of a pattern that will lead StackOverflow down the path that ExpertExchange took.

You would think a company built entirely on the knowledge and experience of the community is serves would make better choices.

Comment: This post has been downvoted well over *twenty* times in the past ten minutes.  What do you think that and all the feedback means?

Comment: I was not aware of the service and was thus surprised about the notification. I got curious and clicked. The post about it above could have been both clearer and briefer. I think I can do better. How about "Our service allowed employers and users to find each other without the expensive and distorting interference of intermediaries. Intermediaries that buy our ads and don't like it when there are cheaper and more effective ways to match supply and demand than them. So they complained. The end."

Comment: Sunsetting the salary calculator is a huge miss. As a newly minted CS graduate with specialized education, it was key in knowing what to negotiate for.

Comment: "Developers, as you all know, don’t have a hard time finding job opportunities." — we don't? Just spent a year looking.

Comment: I deleted my LinkedIn profile years ago because I found Stack Overflow Developer Story and the Jobs board so much better. I received very good and well targeted messages from recruiters (the complete opposite of LinkedIn experience). It's so sad that this awesome tool wasn't seen worth keeping.

Comment: I thought this is a community of "us" . How can this kind of big thing is decided without any voting from the community ?

Comment: Since December I didn't look at any meta topics so I missed this discussion and it was a bombshell when I saw the email announcing that Developer Story will be going away. It'll be sad to see it go. In the end when looking for a new job I didn't get one via SO jobs (LinkedIn worked for me for the first time ever) so I won't miss that much, but Developer Story was something that I loved.

Comment: @Don Reba: Yes, indeed (no pun intended). It is probably [survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias) and restricted to a very small percentage of the United States land area.

Comment: Strange, the Developer story got downvotes when [introduced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313960/1577396) and now downvotes when removing.

Comment: Don't bother with the pdf copy.  It's not very presentable.  I can see why the sunset.

Comment: "how can we leverage our unique position to solve real, meaningful problems for our users and customers?" -- Maybe by helping your users/contributors get hired, and helping some of your customers hire them? I really believe my developer story has helped me get hired (I link it in my resume). SO doesn't have to be "the best" at placing jobs. If you don't want to focus on it that's fine, but why remove what's already there? Are the maintenance costs for maintaining dev story and jobs really that high?

Comment: Maybe figure out a way to monetize, or leverage, your product, without changing it fundamentally. Did you run out of ideas?

Comment: The section "Why?" IMO doesn't offer a credible explanation. SO community is sublime (on both sides of the salary cheque). You're taking away *the best* job platform out there. Please be aware of that.

Comment: Jobs here was a source of hope for long time until I realized that 90% of the interview/testing I had are fake, a single I dont know is enough to get rejected and 100% of them want a robot that hammer the keyboard in little time and viola application finished !! with lowest salary of course. This apply to all other online job boards. I stopped applying to jobs from many years, it hurt and that is enough.

Comment: For those who want a JSON export of Developer Story, you can use https://developerstory.dev instead of the built-in print-to-pdf option!

Comment: "The problem is often finding the right opportunity and job boards and sourcing are ineffective solutions" So, then what are the better solutions? I never found a job any other way!

Comment: Guys. These comments are full of expressions such as "sorry to see it go". Forgive me for being picky (maybe this is my anger speaking), but phrasing it that way dissolves the essence in a way. My feeling is that SO Jobs is not GOING, but a bunch of guys motivated by some petty business reasons MADE a crappy decision, which might be judged as moronic, ill-informed or patronizing (insert your own epithet). I've already added my five cents as an answer, but it was not enough to vent my disappointment. @Puneet Mulchandani if your aim is to drive people away from SO, that's the way!!!

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Wojciech Gac. Jobs has been the best Job Site for software related jobs, period. Reasons cited are contrived. That's what happens when you're giving people brainwashed by management hocus pocus the reigns

Comment:  Very sad to see Developer Story go. It's literally one of the 3 main links I post for myself (including Linkedin and Github profile).
Nice work @Jess Telford for the json export tool https://developerstory.dev/ !
Does anyone know any DeveloperStory alternative webApp?

Comment: I come up with this https://github.com/withpublic/awesome-jobs, free of charge, developer-friendly alternative:)

Comment: I got 2 jobs from SO, so it was quite useful for me. Hope that Employer brands will be as effective

Comment: I really liked SO jobs because the postings here list reasonable expectations and salaries, rather than the "we will expect you to build our entire product for free" type of flim-flam that floods other job search websites. Really sad to see it go...

Comment: Where can I download the PDF from my listing?

Comment: How can this still go ahead??? 90% of negative votes in the answer and A LOT of people annoyed and still not thining of rolling back? THIS IS NONSENSE!! SO exists becaus of the community, not listening to it is an AWFUL MISTAKE!

Comment: SO was the best site to find or look for Jobs as a programmer. Will there be any alternative, or should the comm host their own site about jobs? :o

Comment: Removing Developer story is a really sad thing, I would just send my clients my Developer story link and Top x % in y technology would save me a lot of questions and discussions, and with this change I lost the incentive to spend more time on SO, Please reconsider the change, SO jobs part I can understand but Salary calc, Dev story etc should stay

Comment: StackOverflow recent changes are just bad, all of them, removing developer story, changing UI/UX for a shittier one. What's going on here?

Comment: SO jobs are 10000% more relevant than any other job board.  This is a huge loss and a diminishing of SO's usefulness to me as a SW engineer

Comment: This is a loss to the dev community. Instead of CV I always send my developer story.  These just shakes my faith in stackoverflow as a whole. I hesitate to use any new feature introduced by SO, because No one knows when it will be decommissioned.  Please don't behave like Google. Atleast keep the dev story.

Comment: The jobs section was amazing and should be put there as most of the [people] want jobs and this really helps people

Comment: I dont agree with you guys. Yes there are a lot of websites and apps for job search but for a Software Developer they are not fully qualified as much as Stackoverflow. Here we can also show our professions through the profiles and questions and answers. And lastly there is no place like Stackoverflow for a developer to show himself or herself , please think of this again again take our comments into account

Comment: Personally, I think who ever made this decision and stuck with it might be a little insane. I get the feeling your company will live to regret this rather wonky decision, especially now that more people than ever are working exclusively online from their homes.

Comment: will it be paid service later?

Comment: You should at least keep the developer story (or the traditional CV) feature, as it's the one thing that easily connects achievements (in terms of activity, answers and questions) to a simple high-level picture in form of a CV/story for others and companies to understand.

Comment: "Why?" - and why keep sending annoying emails about discontinuing for the n-th time? Don't you think there are more important things to care about than your f*** SO developer stories anyway?

Comment: I'm stunned - horrid news. I've gotten several jobs because of SO jobs board. Terrible decision. Very disappointed.

Comment: "We feel we don't have a competitive advantage in hosting a platform where you can ask technical questions and have other more experienced users answer them in a structured and concise way."

Comment: Quality was very good. Maybe it was about getting the right value for it? 
Because I believe it was the best jobseeking tool out there.

Comment: I'm not sad to see any of this go. I think it's great that you are making the hard choices to make SO stronger. I've changed jobs several times since posting my developer story, but never used SO in any job search. I'm probably much more typical than those acting like this is a disaster.

Comment: my best job to date was acquired through the SO job board. Please reconsider shutting it down. The quality of postings has been so much higher than the other job boards I have used.

Where is the idea of " ...job boards and sourcing are ineffective solutions" coming from?

Comment: This must be one of the most down-voted post of all times on SO. Why are they still going ahead with this? It could be made into a paid service. If the problem is that it takes away resources from other projects then they could hire a small team to keep it running and pay them from the money it generates. It would be a much more reasonable solution.

Comment: Jobs was dead, but didn't know it yet, when the pricing model was changed to completely price out the startup and small business end of the market, by eliminating the per-job post pricing. I think this is an inevitable result to that poor decision. As an engineering lead for a startup, I'd still use StackOverflow to hire if I could pay by the job over any other mechanism.

Comment: I'm guessing there's something else going on here and SO is trying to position themselves to be acquired, or may have been acquired already, by a company which already has this product. They'll incorporate this tech into their own offering. I am guessing Microsoft. In any case, good luck SO, we love you.

Comment: @MST the decision to sunset jobs was made prior to the acquisition by the current owners, so you could make that assumption, in that it was made in preparation for being acquired by Prosis, but at the end of the day that's just an assumption.

Comment: awww, what a shame.  I loved the way it generated a resume, and it was so easy to keep up to date, I'd just enter new stuff from day to day, and when the day came to job-hunt again, I had everything all organized.

I even wrote something similar for a contract, one of my first big rails jobs, over 10 years ago... you did it SO much better!

Please reconsider, but if not... well, so long, and thanks for all the nibbles!

Comment: As a developer from Mexico, I'm sad to hear about this. The way you guys integrated jobs with the developer profile really made sense to me. I also think that not every developer has it easy to find jobs, especially without a degree, so, stack overflow having a "jobs" section only felt natural to me as someone that is looking for talent and experience... Anyway, farewell jobs </3

Comment: @AlejandroVales This is becoming the standard for SE. They are making changes that the community doesn't support because it makes life easier for them and makes their bottom line look better in the short term, but may end up killing the site when they drive away the user base. It's a common short-sighted problem with companies in general.

Comment: Short version: We realized we weren't making the money we thought we could.

Comment: Seriously? what causing to keep this feature as it is?

Comment: The Developer Story export option isn't really any good. Everything that was unique about the page is missing, and all it does is create a pretty sparse and basic CV out of the entries. The entire reason I used Dev Story was the top % and pluralsight badges it provided beyond what's in a standard CV.

Comment: The most important feature for SO jobs was the the "sponsorship available" option. Its a critical feature. Sad to see it going.

Comment: what a shame, I'm sad to see SO Jobs go. It was one of my favorite places to search and apply to jobs. The application experience felt more consistent between jobs than other sites.

Comment: I don't know what to say but I'm sad to hear that jobs will go, still not able to understand why you are taking this decision ?

Comment: Will we be able to export developer stories in story format rather than CV format before they're removed?

Comment: @ShadSterling I put together a JSON exporter when I heard the news. Might be useful for you: https://developerstory.dev/stackoverflow

Comment: @JessTelford Thank you, that looks neat! (But is blocked at work). Is there an option to make it indexes (or *not* indexed) by Google? And to have an alias for `/story/vonc` to redirect to `/story/<long uuid>`?

Comment: @VonC you read my mind! Both are things I'm working on now. The options will be "Public", "Unlisted" (not indexed, wont show in any future search, but direct URL access will work), and "Private". Any idea why it's blocked at work? The `.dev` TLD perhaps?

Comment: Is it just assumed we would understand what talent functionality might be supported from generic terms like *customer employer branding and company awareness needs*?

Comment: Keep the Salary Calc active and please update the data. Cannot be _that_ hard.

Comment: Damn, this is rough. I use the generated PDF from developer stories as my resume, and will have to go back to manually maintaining my resume. Can you guys open source this functionality or spin it off as a separate service with a subscription?

Comment: "A focus on branding" is a real sly way to say "we are an advertising company now."

Comment: It seems that part of it has already happened. I recently complained [that the PDF export is missing the intro statement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416378/6884), and right now I'm noticing that the current HTML version a) isn't editable anymore and b) is missing the intro statement as well, meaning it's apparently generated by the same thing that does the PDF export.

Comment: I created [devstory.fyi](https://devstory.fyi) with an [import feature](https://devstory.fyi/users/story/preview) that will allow you to migrate and continue managing your story. I'm working to get to feature parity with SO as well as add more features to better showcase developer's work histories. For now, you can import/edit and share (if you want) a public url. I'd love any feedback or bug reports at jon@devstory.fyi :)

Comment: As a SO beta member and heavy user for many years, my usage has dwindled to near zero. The only reason I ever went to SO anymore was the jobs board. As a dev, it's hard not to feel like you're actively trying to chase us away. Employer Marketing? Laughable. I, for one, am completely out. I will click SO links if they appear in a search, but that will be it.

Comment: @codeConcussion will you vote when you visit such links?

Comment: Would have been better to just say: "To bring in more advertising revenue from job boards and recruiters, we have decided to stop competing with them. So, we're going to convert the side panel devoted to jobs into advertising space come April 1st."

Comment: @richardec No. I'll remain signed out of my account. I don't see much of a point trying to participate in a community that doesn't want my participation.

Comment: It's bad news for me i can't search jobs on SO.SO is very big portal for jobs for me.
very sad I really like the overall layout of SO Jobs. it'll be sad to see it go

Comment: A place like Stack Overflow is great for finding developers. Please keep this option is available!

Comment: I wish to express my total rejection of this decision

Comment: why does every company eventually turn into a bunch of management jargon, sales and advert realignment?  because the middle-management of the company, like a cancer, effectively takes control away from the brass and the people doing actual work. not to make anything better, but to make their own needless jobs easier and more secure. at the cost of the soul of the company.

Comment: I got an email that says to download from Developer Story tab... but get this, there is NO developer story tab. Just checked my profile... :(

Comment: Having a developer story was a really comfortable thing. And, I think, a lot of people have had a huge motivation to rise their StackOverflow score, cause it could be reviewed together with their resumes. Now, what's the motivation left to be active here, for the people? And we all need to find a new place to store our resumes. Loose-loose situation.

Comment: If you go to https://www.filenewjob.com/candidates, you can save your story there.

Comment: So long StackOverflow Jobs, thanks for helping me get my first dev shop job with an awesome company. Sorry to see you go! :(

Comment: How sad, this was one of the less spammy ways of applying for a job, where you could connect directly with companies, no recruiters or other bureaucratic steps

Comment: @ChrisSchaller Some good news for you, you can import your story into a FileNewJob developer journey. Just head to http://filenewjob.com/candidates with your Stack public profile URL and within 30 seconds you'll be sorted and your previous vanity slug will be reserved for you too.

Comment: absolutely terrible decision and worse vision from management. Expect a drastic decline in answer quality as SO removes one of the best motivators to keep answering questions on this site for free. I enjoy answering questions but sometimes I justify the time spent to myself by noting how many job offers I effortlessly get through SO. I can't justify the time anymore.

Comment: When I use "Download Jobs data", all I get, for saved jobs, is a _list_ of "companyName" + "jobTitle" (not really useful). I expected to also get the job _description_. Where/How can I get that?

Comment: I'm disappointed with that, because i found some positions very useful and interesting with this platform.

Comment: The constant name changing made me lose track of what is what and what goes where, and so I lost interest very early. It reminds me of a shell game. Is it *"CV"* or is it *"Developer Story"*? Where exactly is it and what is it? Is it on `careers.stackoverflow.com` or is it on `stackoverflowo.com/jobs`? You sent me an email saying you have "migrated" my "CV" to my "Developer Story". But I was invited to "Careers"? Where is Careers? And where is **"Careers 2.0"**? Now you're telling me "Jobs & Talent have been a part of Stack Overflow in some form for almost 12 years". When did "Talent" happen?

Comment: "If you don't know where you're going, any road will get you there." Lewis Carroll, Alice in Wonderland

Comment: To find the right answer you have to start with the right question. This constant name changing indicates that you didn't have a clear idea of what you wanted to do and therefore didn't know how to do it. Like Microsoft! I read the earliest blog posts on this by Jeff. It said something along the line "every developer should have a job they love". This sounds more like a wish than an action plan. I appreciate the thought and I agree. But how do you get there? What is required, what are the obstacles on the way? How long is the road to eternal happiness?

Comment: On one hand, I have to say it's a good riddance. On other hand, it's a sad moment and a loss. It's hard work down the drain for those who worked on this over the years. Lost opportunity and lost momentum. I think this Careers/Jobs/Story ball-wax of ideas was worth exploring. I for one hate job hunting! Number one thing I hate about it is having to submit a CV document like it's 1990s, along with registering the same damn details in a web form. Number two is having to repeat that and create as many new web accounts as there are job ads or companies. Number three is keeping it all updated.

Comment: You can tell how terrible an idea this is that there are still hundreds of jobs listed on SO on the Jobs site's last day. If employers didn't consider it valuable, then they wouldn't be listing jobs. The over 3000 negative votes on here is also a good sign that this is not seen as a positive move.

Comment: I saw remote jobs were still posted the 29 March, not very useful if people receive it in their RSS feed or emails but only open the link in April to see an error.

Comment: Some of my best job opportunities have come to me from SO/Jobs, sad it wont be there when I need it next time. Our history on SO is a solid indicator for employers

Comment: Well that's certainly not *growth*. More like a budget cut.

Comment: Imagine the number of negative feedback for a theoretical announcement of discontinuing the entire Stack Overflow as a service

Comment: Wow, a score of -3451. Does the community support this? I don't think so. Jobs used to be one of the best features of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Day by day SO  reputation is decreasing, I remember when I joined SO, it was so cool.

Comment: You don't have a competitive advantage? What? You have all of the best engineers in one place and a reasonable way to gauge their quality. Everywhere else just has a resume. A top person on SO doesn't even need to be interviewed. Talk about a competitive advantage.

Comment: 2017 abandoned SO Documentation and then 2022 abandoned SO Jobs and next SO itself?

Comment: Would have been nice to get notified that the cv I had saved for years was going to be blown away. Oh well, that is what I get for using someone else's computer for things.

Comment: However much I dislike that SE just decided to throw the Developer Story out along with Jobs, I have to note that you *did* get notified, @pluralMonad, multiple times. SE sent several email reminders during the sunsetting process.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine That is strange then since a search of my entire inbox (spam folder included) did not unearth anything since they announced the migration from the simple CV to developer story. Luckily I had some old exports as PDFs on my local.

Comment: Try searching for "Notice: Discontinuing Stack Overflow Developer Story" - they were supposed to be sent (in total, there should've been 3 emails) to anyone with devstory filled in - does it yield anything, @pluralMonad?

Comment: The is the most downvoted meta question of all time (by a wide margin: -3540 votes vs. the second last at -1132 votes).

Comment: I usually don't bother writing comments on business decision, because I dont have the user data in front of me, but this one seems just bad. It looks like you are going with this MBA/Consulting crap about focusing or about competing. I say this as a business graduate turned developer: Just do great products that people love. If you have a good feature that your users love why sunset it ? SO has enough competence and talent to do whatever you want. SO Jobs was a feature highly reputed both from developers as from companies. I really liked the quality of the jobs offered. Huge miss

Comment: I missed to download my developer story. Is there a hidden link somewhere where I still can download it?

Comment: Stackoverflow jobs was the only place where most job offerings included a salary range. Employers are foaming from the mouth, knowing that they can hide their salaries and rip off employees.

Comment: Aaaand here is when we see the impact of the change of ownership of SO.
I was contacted by the company I work in through here. And I love working where I am. It's sad to think people are going to be missing that opportunity..

Comment: @letie They changed ownership either to new leaders who are extremely incompetent with no overview of the job hunting site market, or poor leadership who accepted a paycheck from linkedin or some other site to shut down their own job. The reasoning the OP gives simply doesnt add up.

Comment: Then what's the whole point of building our profile and getting those points so that we can prove our potential to the client by just sharing our SO profile. This will definitely keep me a bit away from building my SO profile from now onwards.

Comment:  Was going to go job hunting and wanted to update my developer story and was surprised to find it gone. This is such a pity because the design on SO is so much better than linkedin and it was my go to link to share. Quite frustrating.

Comment: I want to post a job for my company, and just found SO job is gone, WTF.

Comment: I got my current Job through StackOverflow. I just came, here again, to check for new onsite jobs, I was shocked to see it is removed.

Comment: This is horrible. I put a ton of work/info into my CV, and now all that data is deleted forever, with hardly any notice! The email notice back in march was NOT enough -- it was too easy to get filtered out. They could have easily put a notification in my SO messages inbox and I would have been much more likely to see it there.

I hope they have some kind of backup somewhere because to just delete that much user data is egregious.

Comment: @BenDavis There were quite a few banners, featured posts, etc prior to this occurring that warned users this was coming.

Comment: It was one of the best ever job searching engines.

Comment: oops, there went my up-to-date CV I guess.  I missed the email back in March... was wondering where all the useful job op ads on the sidebar went to.  Back to dodging dating service catfish on LinkedIn XD

Comment: As of today I'm finally looking for new job opportunities ... only to realize that the most connectable, most sympathic job offering board has closed 7 months ago :(

Comment: I got my first job through SO Jobs. This is a sad day.

Comment: I just added the downvote that made it -4040. Worth the wait.

Comment: What are your plans once ChatGPT-7 puts the Q&A portion of these sites out of business? You had a great thing going with SO Jobs. You were the best around, hands down. I was just about to recommend you to a friend, in fact, which is how I found out about this boneheaded malarkey. As you can tell from this Q&A, you've managed to generate a lot of animosity and lose a lot of loyalty in one fell swoop.

Comment: I've been using stackoverflow since beginning of high school in 2014. 9 years later, I remembered seeing the job site on here and went to find it as I'm searching for my first internship.....and find it's axed. Very sad. I never had a chance to use the feature I grew up with.

Comment: I really like browse through stackoverlfow jobs(espeacilly remote jobs) when there no trend of remote jobs in india.It is like a tool in disposal.Today when i came back today to find it.i could n't find it .It is really sad.i found the discontinue article too.Thanks for support.

Comment: This is the worst decision SO had ever made insulating our efforts here and make us search in another places to apply for jobs despite we are the ones who made it stand and get views from the whole world , Now recruiters & Applicants should  be hopeless

Comment: The best way to find work (or a worker) is to _do your own research_ , and not depend on some 'dating service' algorithm. Most people use SO to advertise their skills and knowledge. SO is moving in the right direction by refocusing on employer advertising. SO is simply getting out of the way by removing the 'dating service'. Users and employers can still find each other on the site.

Comment: I just went to SO Jobs just to see it shut down a year ago. It was the one place I went to to look for jobs because it was so well designed. The fact they shut it down is the most mind-bogglingly absurd decision the company could have made. It was the one feature that kept me coming back to Stack Overflow. What an absolutely crazy business decision.

Comment: Developer story and job board was a cool feature. sad to know you're dropping it. If possible please back it again.

Comment: How much money did you save by removing a job board from your website? Was that feature like super difficult to maintain costing tons of man-hours etc? I really doubt it. I find it odd you cannot pivot to launching the "employer branding and company awareness" features we all were waiting for without deleting the job board. Is SO just running on some $5 a month droplet with 512MB of storage space? I don't get it. Selling job advertisement space to employers seems like low hanging fruit at minimal expense. If there's a surplus of developer job boards, who cares? It's not a competition.

Comment: Why would users share knowledge and answer questions if they cannot reap a benefit from the knowledge transfer. You have disincentivized half of your content creators. Don't be surprised if you have a lot of unanswered questions. I have yet to find any of these employer branding features or company awareness features on the site. Where can I click to read about any employer's stance on environmental and social policies (aka political ideology) or learn the company's slogans and about their "culture" so I know where not to send my resume?

Comment: Bro, Finding a job is real, meaningful problems for your users. really upset of this move.

Answer (score 1672):

I have not been looking forward to this day. I've been on both sides of the SO Jobs thing and really liked both. I think this is a loss to the development community at large.

As a job candidate, I've used it extensively. I've also provided [*some* feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A189134+%5Bjobs%5D+is%3Aquestion) on it over the years. Not all of it has been positive, but I think it's been constructive and helpful in, at least, showing various use cases. SO Jobs helped me find my current role. It was invaluable during my job search. The signal-to-noise ratio of the board is much higher than others I was using at the time and continues to be today.

Which brings me to the other side of SO Jobs. I've used the board to hire over 20 engineers in the past 3 years. Stack Overflow provides the *best* candidates compared to other inbound candidate pipelines. I've been looking, unsuccessfully, since the initial announcement that SO Jobs was shutting down for something that provides even close to the quality of candidates and have yet to find one. The noise of other locations is extreme and I am not looking forward to April 1 right now.

---

Something that I ask you to reconsider: Keep the salary calculator. I thought this was maintained based off the yearly developer survey. I believe this feature is helpful to the developer community. As someone who has searched for jobs, it is helpful to know roughly what I should be expecting. As someone who hires, it has been mentioned during salary discussions enough times that I know other developers utilize it. It helps to keep us honest, in terms of salary expectations when hiring for a role. While my company publishes a salary range for its roles, for those that do not - or for those candidates that wish to see if the ranges are appropriate - the calculator can be very helpful in salary discussions.

Comment: Just a quick note: the salary calculator _is_ based off the developer survey, but specifically the 2019 developer survey. It has not been updated since then. I also liked the salary calculator as a feature, but it becomes increasingly less useful when the data starts getting stale because no one is infusing fresh data.

Comment: @animuson Out of curiosity... _why_ is no one infusing fresh data? Surely that could be easily automated?

Comment: @animuson Then can we update the data? Or worst case just open source the salary calculator and release anonymized data? I've no doubt a number of people, myself included, would be willing to help upkeep it.

Comment: @animuson There were developer surveys in 2020 and in 2021, too. Why there were no one to import the new data? The company is big and until now I knew it so, Job SO is one of its top money maker.

Comment: @Clonkex I think, doing something once in a year, maybe it is cheaper by hand.

Comment: The irony of the most useful feature not having been updated since '19 is not lost on me...

Comment: Given, since the survey data is public and anonymized, couldn't someone recreate the salary calculator based on the same data (both now and in the future)?

Comment: Did they ask about salary in the 2020 and 2021 surveys? I know the survey question sets have been pretty wacky the last couple years, so they may have just not included that info.

Comment: Yes, the 2020 and 2021 surveys asked for the salary as well. It's just that the data wasn't used to update the salary calculator.

Comment: I am really Sad that SO Jobs are going away. I have personally used it extensively and frequently recommend to lots of people in my network. Please reconsider.

Comment: It was also a shame when the ability for companies to reach out to users was removed. One company I'm working for hired much of our development team that way, now we're struggling significantly using other methods. As a candidate, I've gotten two contracting opportunities that way. I've tried several other sites to find contracting work, but none work as well as SO, partly because SO highlights my skills so much better than other sites. I'm really sad to see developer stories go away because it's in all my resumes I send out to companies when applying/bidding to jobs.

Comment: The mods removing comments of people lashing against this decision is the new SO meta.

Comment: @WalterMonecke People being unconstructively antagonistic and nasty towards anyone, including the company, has never, and will never, be allowed anywhere on Stack Exchange. There are plenty of valid critiques that are sticking around just fine– the attacks, however, should not.

Comment: Really crappy decision and just decided without consulting.

Comment: Personally, I understand the decision. But it is so very sad to see SO jobs go. I don't know how to feel right now, but we hope for the best.

Comment: The salary calculator could be open-sourced or (more likely) recreated using updated data. If someone is able to recreate the model using the 2021 developer survey (or they open-source that part of the project) I'd be happy to create the frontend, backend and even host it.

Comment: Sounds like a bad April Fools joke

Comment: "Stack Overflow provides the best candidates compared to other inbound candidate pipelines." I found this to be true as well. SO has had a competitive advantage for years. I've recommended StackOverflow as THE place to find qualified developers. For one job I posted, the first SO applicant and subsequent applicants were all better than applicants found by other means. And the support from the SO rep was top notch.

Comment: I wanted to chime in and say that while I haven't gotten a position through Jobs, I had incredible opportunities through it and made very valuable connections. The signal to noise ratio was the best of any job board I could find. I'm also sad about Developer Story. I really liked having it connected to my account. Finally as someone who hires SO boards was priced out of reach for my company for a bit. We just got big enough to afford it. Not mad - business is business - but I am disappointed.

Comment: This post is the first I downvoted, I hate this decision. It is disappointing and frustrating, I received many wonderful and personalised recommendations through SO (it is the best platform for this kind of thing imo). Obviously it is your business so also your prerogative to do what you see fit and I have no choice but to respect it but please reconsider.

Comment: Salary calculator going makes sense. Levels.fyi or other options would be better to continue to crowdsource proven offers. That said I also got my job from a recruiter through stack overflow. Makes sense but I feel this could have been a great area for stack overflow to shine with a unique landing page instead of a GitHub profile landing page.

Comment: Has part of this decision involved privacy issues? I made a change to my Dev Story yesterday and today I already received a call on my private home number today where they used this new information.

Comment: I wish this is an April fool prank.

Comment: I bet money that SO was paid to shut this feature down. The amount of transparency it enforced with posting salary ranges and salary calculators was threatening to some employers. Thus the feeble leaders at SO bent the knee for a nice pay-check.

Answer (score 455):

Out of my long tenure at Stack Overflow, I spent a year as a product manager. My very first task in that role was leading the technical part of the transition from the old Careers CV to the new Developer Story.

A part of that was figuring out how to handle the "custom name", which allowed you to share your CV (and later Developer Story) without an ID in the URL, just your name -- like `/story/hans-olo`.

"Custom name" was the official name for this feature (later renamed to "public link"), but internally it was called the "vanity slug", which caused me, in one of the first specs I wrote as a PM, to draw this epically underappreciated visual pun:

[image]

Well, Dev Story, you had a good run. I once [had high hopes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321017/115866) in you, but it looks like you weren't meant to be forever.

Rest in peace, Vanity Slug. ❤️

Comment: This feedback might be a little late :D But I quite like how LinkedIn does it.

Comment: feels like there should be a `/story/hans-yolo`, too

Comment: I, for one, will miss the vanity slug. SO Jobs itself? Not so much. Either way, time to update my (PDF) CV and remove the link to my Developer Story. Sigh.

Comment: The vanity slug pic is really good. It had a sort of sadness to it but I'm sure that's just because I'm seeing it given the current news. Thanks for sharing. I remember making a picture of a random dev password we generated to help me remember it.

Comment: hi @balpha, been a while! I remember this, it was during my first year at Stack! Sunsetting these features has definitely felt bittersweet. Thanks again for everything you've done for Dev Story, and more generally for Stack, over the years

Comment: Love the vanity slug!  Love it! :)

Comment: Despite the bad news, this "vanity-slug" was epic!

Comment: Folks, let's replicate the Developer Story ourselves, somewhere, since Stack does not want it anymore. Who's in? Maybe I will see you guys on Github.

Comment: @eppineda Did you post a github link?

Comment: @AkinOkegbile It appears someone else has started: https://github.com/jogboms/developer-story. (You are the first person to respond to my suggestion!)

Comment: You can save your vanity slug by visiting https://www.filenewjob.com/candidates and importing your story, we'll even automatically allocate the same vanity slug to you!

Answer (score 380):

> The effort it would take us to truly differentiate in this space is not one we could justify

I disagree. I think the amount of effort Stack Overflow would need to differentiate in this space is zero.

It's not about the tech, it's about the types of people that use it. My experience with the SO job boards has been that of much higher quality, more relevant jobs than LinkedIn or Indeed. I don't know what it's like from the other side, but I get hundreds of irrelevent messages on LinkedIn vs a handful of relevant messages here.

Sad times.

**Edit:** A couple of other thoughts following comments.

I'll add a quote from the ["Why use jobs"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-use-jobs) page:

> We're as committed to putting you in control of your job search as we are to helping you get answers to your programming questions

That page lists a rule against most of the problems I have with a site like LinkedIn. I think this is the thing that separates SO to me, you build a community around solving coding problems, and provide a selection of curated additional tools, while guarding that community against [spam recruiter messages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-is-recruiter-spam). That the site is able to do that sets it apart from my perspective, and shows much more respect for the time of its users than other companies. It's a shame that other job boards don't have something similar.

I also understand that there's a cost to maintaining a job portal that may not see a great amount of use, which is hard to justify for a company that provides a free product but needs to pay wages.

I almost want a site with a job portal that doesn't get used much. It means users are choosing to engage when they're looking to move. I think there could be a pipeline that feeds into this, say using the current salary tool to then highlight other jobs, but understand this takes development time and has a maintenance/operation cost, which may not be easy to justify.

I think SO does a great job supporting its community, although I know that's not always a smooth or easy process.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback and I’m glad to hear you had positive experiences with Jobs. When we look at overall usage & engagement, though, less than 1% of our monthly users engaged with Jobs and, of those, most never received any messages from employers. Most employers found our sourcing system too restrictive or difficult to work with. (1/2)

Comment: We would need to spend a lot more time & effort to address these issues, and we’d likely still be behind competing products where recruitment is their primary focus. We’d rather spend that effort on improving our core platform and products that are more closely aligned with it. (2/2)

Comment: Thank you for the reply and clarification, I understand your concerns. I think the appeal of the platform is that it's not recruitment focused, strange though it sounds I almost feel like the low engagement numbers are a good thing. It means there's a community around a common problem, with extra tools provided when useful, one of those being a job portal that (in my experience) has a smaller selection of higher quality job adverts than other sites. Unfortunately, I also understand that from a business perspective, with cost of development, that's probably not a good business case.

Comment: LinkedIn by comparison, much of the focus is around personal branding or recruitment. So drive by messages from recruiters that haven't bothered reading my profile seem to be common place. I think because the focus isn't on recruitment here, that practice is much lower.

Comment: I might just not like the whole process of finding a job.

Comment: I suppose what's lacking within the industry is more a "specialized job board", I'm a bit of a niche software engineer/data science/HPC person anyway, and a lot of jobs aren't relevant to me.

Comment: My experience with being contacted by recruiters via SO mimics yours of being contacted by drive-by recruiters on linkedin. Neither has been a good source for organic job prospects, if you want something you have to go get it/make connections. Inflating your rep in the hopes that it'd attract a company via your profile is laughable

Comment: @KevinB fair, I've only used stack overflow jobs twice (one of which led to my current job), so my sample size isn't great, but I've never had messages from recruiters unless I've set my profile to looking for jobs. LinkedIn I got those once or twice a week until I disabled my account. I wouldn't bother trying to inflate my profile score here to help my job search, you're right that's silly, and not really the point I was trying to make.

Comment: I think one issue overlooked is that recruiters don't want to jump through the additional hoops unless they're some level of desperate: so despite the postings being higher quality, the companies themselves often are not. It was useful when my career was getting started, but there hasn't been a single posting I would even consider engaging with in the past ~8 years of occasionally browsing.

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani `Most employers found our sourcing system too restrictive or difficult to work with.` - And that's what would actually be a big plus for devs - it filters out employers who only use automated mailing lists with hundreds of robots-recruiters.

Comment: IMO linkedin can not seriously be used as a job platform. so the comparison is lacking. but there ARE better job platforms out there.

Comment: I'm curious what other space there is where recruiters aren't allowed to advertise jobs and so it cuts out the meddling middle-person and helps developers hire and be hired? Anyone know of a similar site?

I cannot help but assume this is money driven and they want to allow recruiters to advertise instead - lazy, easy money. Man, I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani That is quantitative, not qualitative argument. I'm sure that over time, you would be the place to go for great developers.
Also, why not let the community to build that part of the SO as an open source?

Comment: @ZPiDER any suggestions? Ironically, I just had a look for some recommendations, the top tend to be either GitHub or StackOverflow, which I kinda like, it's the "there when you need it, don't harass our users" type product.

Comment: Maybe the trouble is that industry recruiters aren't nerdy enough to use the job boards and, instead, prefer to mass-spam us without bothering to actually target their talent?

Comment: I always kind of viewed SO jobs as being for the recruited, and not designed for the recruiter. Thats what make it so appealing to your users. Maybe you were trying to market it to the wrong crowd. I'm always excited when I start a new job hunt, until I unexpectedly apply to a recruiting firm that won't stop calling me with useless job offers i'm neither interested in nor a good fit for.

Comment: "We're as committed to putting you in control of your job search as we are to helping you get answers to your programming questions" -- only logical conclusion: Stack Overflow Questions are being sunset next... ;)

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani: would maybe be interesting if you could list some of these competitors you feel are ahead of StackOverflow in this space? Like others, I’ve always thought SO Jobs was miles ahead in terms of the quality of jobs and candidates. Do you consider competitors are ahead even on these bases? I can understand this might not generate enough revenue, but then at least be honest and say “Whilst we were the best developer job board out there, it simply wasn’t making enough money”. If there are competitors you feel are ahead on these bases, I’d love to know who; I’ve never found them.

Comment: @extempl *The 1% mentioned here occurs because **users here don't have unlimited knowledge nor employers have unlimited funds** as well*. People here are sincere, they openly accept of *knowing not enough*, while in LinkedIn so many people lie about *probably already knowing everything just perfect*. 1/2

Comment: It's as elsewhere a Gaussian distribution of skills and knowledge levels - however SoF is a place where users can accrue -- in the fastest mode -- an extended level of knowledge and raise their real levels as a consequence. Here users want to "buy knowledge", on LinkedIn they want to brag about it - not even to successfully "sell" it there. 2/2

Comment: "It's not about the tech, it's about the types of people that use it." Bingo. That's exactly what I'm going to miss the most about it. I feel I've shared more job postings from SO even when I'm not looking for a job. There's something magical about the synergy that your get here and something that many other places as a seeker you cannot get, and in hiring, I've had an enormously fruitful time being able to see how people choose to interact and communicate with SO that has led to better candidates and hirings.

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani "less than 1% of our monthly users engaged with Jobs and, of those, most never received any messages from employers. Most employers found our sourcing system too restrictive or difficult to work with."  I think that 1% of monthly users looking for a new job sounds high, not low.  That means that the typical user is looking for a job about once every ten years.  Five years if you figure that half the users have alternate job search methods.  And a restrictive/difficult sourcing system filters out the bad jobs, which is why prospective employees like it.

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani the metrics you mentioned are only half of the story. As many have commented, there has been extremely positive experiences for developers looking for jobs. On a developer centred platform, that is the point, isn't it? Also, 1% isn't too bad considering not everyone is looking for a job.  Maybe talk to employers who have had a good experience, check with developers who have had a good experience, and find out how to replicate that. SO jobs seems devoid of recruiters and this is a good thing. OR, release it as a open source project and let the community take it over.

Comment: Pretty sad to see this go... I used this as my resume for the last 5 or so years.  It worked well.  Oh well. why would a company keep a service people actually like.

Comment: So because less than 1% of SO visitors are actively looking for a new job, the job site has no value? I would be interested to know what the expected percentage of developers/technical people who are actively looking for a new job at a given time is - I would assume it is well under 10%, as that would seem an extremely high churn rate (for example, I once worked for a small company of 30 people that had on average 1 employee join or leave a month, and that seemed very unstable, and is only 3%)

Comment: I agree 100%. I haven't used SO jobs much but when I have, the interaction I've had was very relevant. My first 6 figure job, I got through SO jobs after months of what was essentially spam on LinkedIn and other places. When I next wanted to switch jobs I was headhunted but I had been getting interesting interview offers on SO jobs and the sad thing for me is I was expecting to update my developer story with a new job that I'm starting in 10 days, April 11th in my time zone, that I also got through SO jobs while indeed, and others are giving me mostly irrelevant matches.

Comment: Yeah thanks, the Developer Story was my resume. Doesn't make sense why that needed to be removed and Jobs- SO was the best place for devs to look.  Prashanth must be out of touch.

Comment: I'm disappointed to hear this. I always enjoyed browsing the recommended jobs in the sidebar whenever I visited SO. I landed my current (awesome, fully remote) job through SO Jobs 5 years ago. I would have probably never heard of the company had it not been for SO Jobs.
I really liked the fact that SO Jobs was integrated with SO. I already had an SO profile, and I already visit SO for other reasons, so having Jobs integrated was very convenient. I'm not a fan of having to sign up for single-purpose job boards. Integration with a service I already use is much nicer.

Comment: It is truly remarkable how bad this decision was. I mean, look at these comments: *Not a single person thinks this was a good idea*. Well, I didn't read them all but out of the 40 or so I read 100% of them strongly disapproved.

Answer (score 282):

Well this is sad.  Does SO now have a parent company that understands only revenue and not how useful a jobs board is on a site like SO?

Discontinuing the jobs board is a profoundly bad move, and an insult to your faithful users over the years.

Comment: You do realize that this decision was made and announced before the acquisition, and that the parent company has nothing to do with it? Conspiratorial thinking to blame it on someone else may be the easy out, but the blame for making this decision rests entirely on us and no one else. Please don't bring irrelevant factors into it.

Comment: @animuson Thanks, it helped a lot! Sorry I had no intent to do that; I never forgot to mention that the for us available *facts* are not enough to have a clear answer. Now I am trying to understand the aihr link mentioned in the post. The content is clearly for companies and not for employee, as also the paying customers of the Job SO were companies and not we. :-) If I understand it well, the company is now probably trying to create some employer branding solution, I am very curious for it, altough probably not I will be a paying customer for that as well.

Comment: _"an insult to your faithful users"_ I think you overestimate how valued the "Jobs" section is, to most users. I've heard a lot of _"Why is SE invested in jobs?! It's a Q&A site!"_, over the years. Besides, as the announcement mentioned, there are better platforms out there.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is room enough for opinions on both sides.  I think SO is a logical place for persons with high technical ability to connect with employers seeking certain skillsets.

Comment: @Cerbrus "Better platforms out there?"  I think SO users who have found gainful employment on SO's jobs board would agree SO's board is more than sufficient.

Comment: Your opinion is clear, Keith; You don't need to repeat that twice. Jobs has never been the primary drive for users to visit this platform, and as I said, there are plenty of regulars that would prefer if the company spent more time on improving the Q&A side, instead. There _are_ other platforms that do "jobs" just as well, if not better. I'm not saying Jobs didn't function, I'm saying that it's not the end of the world that it's being shut down.

Comment: @animuson I read finally [this](https://stackoverflow.com/talent/solutions). Well, my opinion about the Job SO closure, as I wrote in my deleted post, did not change. But I wish you to have more luck with it as I can predict.

Comment: When reading rigid opinions as "SO should better focus on what it does better, which is improving Q&A", just wonder what would be Google today if would stubbornly only develop Google Search, so no Gmail, no Maps, no AdSense, no Android, no Chrome, no NodeJS, no anything else would appear, can you imagine such horror story? Or imagine going in a restaurant, asking "I would like a pizza" and being answered "only orange juice here or else go out from here", would you ever visit again that place? Google put it well "do not do evil" to the users. Well said: because *users created the Q&A content*

Comment: @animuson 'this decision rests entirely on us and no one else' ... it is always refreshing to hear the truth, so let us know if it's not actually some scenario where once taking a framework and setting a forum online with user created content, in several months / or years? but why years? / after polishing everything on it, the employees there cannot explain to their employer why they are still getting paid. Oups ?? So they start suggesting "let's do this or that instead", "killing" the well living platform after delivering it, just to deserve their salary (any "definition of done", anyone?)

Comment: @Eve My thoughts exactly. As the best QA site, there's not much else to improve apart from keeping it 100% fast & available. So managers gotta manage something, developers gotta code something. Funny thing is I suppose the monetization of Jobs was super healthy, why not just add/remove random bars/buttons/tabs/columns as usual?

Comment: SO job board was my first option whenever I started looking for Jobs, so sad to see it go. But nothing I can do as a user, the management has made it choice

Answer (score 240):

Although I have known for some time that Talent/Jobs was going away, I didn't realize that Developer Story would be part of that sunset.  That's profoundly disappointing; I know traction wasn't super, super great on that feature, but I actually *use* it when applying for jobs (granted, with [modifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374740/153187)).  Is there any chance of getting someone to take over this feature in some way?  LinkedIn doesn't quite cut it in my opinion.

**Edit:** On a personal note, even before I worked at Stack, I thought what was then Stack Overflow Careers was the best developer job board available.  I applied *to* Stack through it, and I've used it since, both from the employer side and the candidate side.  I still haven't found one I think works as well, and while I certainly have some bias -- and knew this time would come -- it's still sad to see this fine product -- and the work we did on it -- go away.  Thank you to everyone who worked on it, and props to my former colleagues for making something that helped developers with their careers in a real, tangible way, at least for a few years.

Comment: _"Is there any chance of getting someone to take over this feature in some way?"_ Do you mean someone _internal_ at Stack, or something more like [Cassidy's Polywork page](https://www.polywork.com/cassidoo)? I wonder if a feature like Developer Story can stand alone as a product without Talent/Jobs supporting it?

Comment: @JessTelford Closer to the latter.  I happen to know that the Dev Story codebase has almost nothing to do with the Jobs/Talent codebase ([Conway's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law) at work), but I'm thinking more of "can we have a thing that takes Dev Story data in some form and puts it on a page."  It could lend more credibility if Stack _did_ host it -- maybe as an optional feature of the Stack user profile instead of something separate -- but I don't know that there's interest.  Heck, even a way to get close via a GitHub profile page would be better than nothing.

Comment: Jobs was so much better than anything else out there. Your underestimating it's value to the community and your company.

Comment: Because dev story doesn't require active work on their part, just data saved by users and stats pulled from the site itself, I am surprised they feel the need to sunset it too. It's a low risk, low cost feature that increases interest and engagement they don't need to remove when they remove something that actually takes effort and they aren't seeing gains from.

Comment: it is truly pathetic to see a company that offered something decent, that took it almost zero maintenance on their part decide to discontinue it even though the site is pretended to be governed by it's users.

Comment: Can't believe it I only found out about this today, although I had been noticing the lack of ads for a while now, but thought that was just a change in the reaction to my job preferences. Anyway, just to add to the chorus that this is really sad. StackOverflow was by far the best job listing platform I have ever used. Besides the cool interface and the interesting ads, what stood out for me is that if felt like most of the jobs ads came directly from the companies, instead of recruiters. I hope some other company follows the same approach or that this will return some day...

Answer (score 172):

Please keep the salary calculator around. Yes, the data is out of date, but that can presumably be fixed without a ton of effort.

If you *don't* want to maintain it, please open source it and release the relevant raw data (anonymized, of course). The community will certainly maintain it.

Comment: I think the numbers of the salary calculator are surreal for my region, but it is still more than nothing. Glassdoor/Kununu gave for me more exact results (if I compare them to the companies I know).

Comment: The dataset is available here: https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey. Someone needs to reverse-engineer it. I have some thoughts on how to do it but not the time right now.

Comment: @Harshvardhan That's why it should just be open-sourced. If they're not going to use it, there's no reason they shouldn't do that.

Answer (score 105):

> and job ads

Sad day. I spent four years of my life building and maintaining those things. At least the company ads still have a bit of life left...

But all things change. Hopefully this decision frees up Stack to do many more successful things!

Comment: Yes, this is sad. Most software has a limited lifespan (for whatever reason). Hopefully some general software components and/or gained knowledge can live on.

Comment: "Job ads" may cease to exist but there are future problems to solve that may require the structure and capabilities implemented previously

Comment: "Greed" is different from "we need to keep the servers running, the lights on, and make sure employees get paid". If an endeavor costs more money than it makes, it is unsustainable, regardless of how many people are attached to it. The bottom line is that these business ventures did not pan out, and did not even make "break even" revenue. Continuing to throw money down the drain would be insanity and would eventually lead to collapse.

Comment: @rossipedia And would you please tell me how you know this is unprofitable? Maybe it's just not profitable "enough"?

Comment: Whether it's not profitable "at all" or just not profitable "enough" the outcome/conclusion is still the same.

Comment: "Hiring software engineers is quite a profitable business"  
For the 5 years I worked for SO, that was definitely not true at all.

Comment: @rossipedia "Smart boss, simple worker: wage decrease, worktime increase; smart worker, simple boss: wage increase, worktime decrease or both; smart boss, smart worker: wage increase, worktime decrease, profit increase"

Comment: The fees for recruiting devs were really high. Can't see how this wasn't profitable. The high fees were justified, since you had a unique position in the market. Still can't believe that storing this data would cost more than you make with selling it  

Comment: Terrible decision. One that SO leadership will regret later on.

Comment: They could have made job boards a paid feature. I would way rather use SO jobs than LinkedIn Premium at $40/mo.

Answer (score 102):

While I understand the decision, it's sad to see the Developer Story going away, and so soon. It was always a good place to showcase one's achievements both on Stack Overflow and worldwide. I hope that some of its features could creep back into the plain Stack Overflow user profile in the future.

Comment: Prosus (the company who bought SO) is just pushing greed. This is a result of that. Why keep something we devs like but makes little money when you can put those engineers and resources to "better" use?

Comment: @WalterMonecke I hadn't paid enough attention to that, but now a lot of things make sense - they're tearing down what made SE great, wrecking the user interface, chopping off used parts of it and trying to 'streamline' into something that will probably end up seeing their usership drop then wonder why everyone left...

Comment: I _don't_ understand the decision. I expected Jobs charges companies for each post. Isn't that a way to make money. Why drop a feature that makes money. I'd understand if they drop _maintenance_, but why drop the feature?

Comment: @PabloH because in their minds it's probably not profitable enough or the current generated revenue doesn't justify the purchase price Prosus paid. They will try tome come up with new "features".

Comment: @PabloH Jobs was likely a commercial failure because it was improperly priced in its entirety, focusing on mega-corp budget acquisition (I was a potential customer). I agree that Prosus is doing this _out of what they think is greedy_, however, as a developer entrepreneur myself I have to criticize the decision. IMO, at best this is business incompetence given the economic attention to human capital acquisition during the middle of the pandemic. At worst, it's some internal corporate demagogue's pet project. Regardless, it entirely ignores the inflationary + supply pressures everywhere.

Comment: @JasonRStevensCFA this was in process before Prosus, FYI

Comment: @KevinB Thank you for the heads up! I find the entire decision tree incredibly fascinating from a business perspective.

Comment: @SztupY I have created a feature request https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416017/request-for-some-features-to-remain-after-sunsetting-developer-story

Answer (score 93):

They were the only job listings I enjoyed reading, and I saw them several times a week (when I wasn't at work, where I usually use an extension to hide them. Seems wrong to read them at work).

> We are realigning the Talent business to focus more on customer employer branding and company awareness needs, and moving away from job slots and direct hiring.

Don't get me wrong; I'm going to be *very* happy never to be told to update my developer story again.

But I've never understood this shift. It would be interesting if you could share what that really means beyond -- idk, more general ads?

I mean, you said this...

> Developers and technologists often want to learn about companies as they begin to evaluate opportunities in order to understand things like the company culture, the work/life balance, the social and environmental policies, the tech stack, and the learning and development opportunities companies offer. This is collectively referred to as “Employer Branding.”

If jobs aren't a part of that "branding and needs", why is your user base going to view that content? **Why do I care about a company's work/life balance if I don't want to apply?** I can tell you the *only* reason I ever access that content now is to see if I want to work at that company.

Is this going to be like the IBM commercials I see during football games? I've always wondered who those influence. They're so generic, and just say "cloud" over and over without any data, it's gotta be for non-technical managers. They sure don't appeal to me, someone who can spell "zeroes and ones".

In other words, how does a focus on 3rd party branding mesh with devs who are *by definition of being here* focusing on the nuts and bolts of software development, not making brands? Other sites, maybe (??), but SO? :confused: If the goal is to entice devs to work at companies and *remove* the conduit to apply and see open jobs, how do you show companies it's working? Because you provide earmarked links to their own careers page? Is that what we're doing -- dropping the overhead of running and matching listings?

Or are your new clients like Linode and Azure and AWS? Mongo vs. Cosmos? Are the adverts supposed to have us try out techs and sell their providers to our managers? That makes more sense to me, but doesn't really fit with the lifestyle stuff in your "Employer Branding" description, though.

Idk. Recruiters around here take home 20% of a new hire's first year's pay from the company using them to hire. And oh *man* they're worth it right now. Maybe you're not charging enough? Or allowing enough companies to use your services?

What you've got are interested, motivated devs reading your site every day. Seems you'd do better to pivot to selling cellular subscriptions, training sites, VR, and, idk, home mortgages than descriptions of tech companies' work/life balance.

Or, you know, have you thought of running job openings? `;^D`

Comment: I think the meaning of these sentences is that they remove the Job SO and no more. They suggest existing customers to use other, already existing SO services (teams, ads), but none of these are meant to step into the place of the Job SO. I can only hope that it will be more gain for them than harm.

Comment: As far as I understand, they just use this practically meaningless marketing jargon to say that they are going to monetize the job offerings. If someone wants to publish a job, they must pay and the transactions between potential employees and employers will go through SO and not directly.

Comment: This feels like part of the same trend as Google no longer showing good search results. If you give people easy access to the thing that they're actually looking for, it's harder to sell advertising as it's no longer needed.

Answer (score 88):

I think that **Developer Story** is **extremely useful** part of the SO.

The section that displays that you are in **x%** of all time answerers for some technologies is really useful. You can add that info in your resume and use it when applying to positions relevant to these technologies.

Maybe you can reconsider to leave the **Developer Story** section?

Comment: Is it though? I've seen resumes come across my desk for people who claim to be in the upper percentile for technology that I'm hiring for (like Spring), and yet they've never seen "Failed to load ApplicationContext" during the normal course of their tenure at wherever it was they worked.  Also, the Developer Story is strictly not opt-out and it's kinda stuck there once you fill it out.  That's probably an issue with some newer laws now.

Comment: @Makoto, Precisely, with SO it is possible to easily check this information. Similarly, you can analyze the answers to estimate the level of the candidate.

Comment: @NeNad, At a minimum, I hope the section with **x%** will be retained.

Comment: I totally agree! @vernou

Comment: I would even be willing to pay a small annual subscription fee for the convenience of not having to maintain some HTML/CSS or Word document and hosting it somewhere publicly available.

Answer (score 83):

The removal of the Developer Story is quite unfortunate. The links to my Developer Story, along with my GitHub, were large factors in me getting my first development job. It's a nice overview that links to my profile if they want more depth.

I suppose I can just link directly to my profile, but that's not the same. Being able to combine my SO accomplishments with my life accomplishments in one page was really nice.

Comment: Isn't there an export button? Use that as basis for an CV. That said, I've only had to use an CV with my internship. All jobs after that were basically employers that found me through LinkedIn, or word of mouth.

Comment: @Cerbrus You can export the Traditional View, ya. I liked having it hosted so I can link to it though. I had it so my resume was less developer-focused, and then links to my GitHub/SO profile highlighted my developer traits. Maybe I just to focus my resume? Regardless, I found it to be nice supplemental material to provide with my resume.

Comment: @Cerbrus you can export, but there's some issues with that. First it's static data, I'm curently top 10% for SQL, I could answer more questions and end up top 5% or top 1% but there's nowhere to get that update once it's sunset, second having the page under SE's control put higher trust value in the data from those % and pluralsight badges. It gave an independent place to verify that top 10% SQL on the site and 277/300 pluralsight IQ in TSQL. That's what's lost with static, exported data.

Answer (score 78):

Couldn't differentiate yourself? but you were already the only good place to look for a job, by a wide margin!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you found the quality of listings higher on SO Jobs, this was  one of the key principles we followed when making product decisions. Unfortunately, traffic alone wasn't enough of a differentiator in the recruitment tech space and we were lagging behind other competing products when it came to candidate engagement. If you're interested, check out the related comment I made on [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415408/6518788).

Comment: "You" have a self-sustainable community right now. Keep removing features and switch the focus from the users/helpful content, to more commercial stuff. But, good luck in the chosen direction, it will be fun to watch how bad decisions destroy good stuff.  In this way, you will see a different kind of sunset.

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani if possible post a link to a relevant chat about this topic (if there is such 1), as probably comments here don't allow for extended discussions on it. Users perceive Jobs not as a "product" as you call it but instead as a service, if possible even with "continuous delivery" / and improvement / at their end, not something done once, therefore ready, delivered, then dead. I wonder if you couldn't just use the platform to ask *users* about how to improve this "product" (many could recognize the best Jobs offers service aspects when they see it) or *marketing experts* here, too

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani SO jobs is way better than other platforms(and it has the most related jobs unlike other job board websites), removing it definitely will hurt most of ours future job search. Removing useful features will only hurt engagement further. Great advice from Eve that you can basically ask your users here about how to improve these features instead of killing it. No business knows better than their users. My $0.02

Answer (score 73):

I wish this post would include some bold warning, like "**Hey, go to your https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/current and export it, because you know, we're killing CVs**".

It's just sad that people at SO care so little about users data. There is no indication in Profile tab as well.

**Edit:** I see there is timeline where indicators for users will appear somewhere undecided date in February, BUT, why this is not first step after publishing this post?

Why wait if everything is decided? Users should see notices in their profiles right after this post appeared, optionally linking to this post.

Comment: "February 2022 – users will start to see banners and notices on all deprecated features" this will occur in the very near future.

Comment: "> Late January 2022 – users will no longer be able to create new Developer Stories" well, this will bang them as well without notice, but I see what yo mean

Comment: Being unable to create new ones, doesn't prevent exporting

Comment: Still this timeline makes little sense, edited my answer.

Comment: The banner explaining that developer story will be going away will go live at the same time we stop allowing new stories to be created, sometime in January. The February timeline is for adding notices to other Jobs features. There also isn't any export feature for developer story yet, unless you want it as a static PDF. That feature isn't coming until March.

Comment: Instead of ranting right away, you should have taken the time to actually read the post. In addition to the banners others have already mentioned it also says "Early March 2022 – users will be able to easily export all their data related to Jobs & Developer Story"

Comment: @idmean isntead of poor communication, you should notify users in a more practical way instead of writing poorly written post somewhere in meta, and also I lost you at "Why?" section, so

Comment: @Kos I did not write that post but I was indeed able to understand it just fine.

Comment: @animuson I think many users [have been trained to ignore those banners](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/799502). I hope I'm wrong though.

Comment: @41686d6564 Not using those banners, at least not for the dev story notices.

Comment: Additional warnings and notices will appear closer to the date, these are currently in development. Most of the export features already exist but they’re in a few different places and typically scoped to exporting all your data, not just what’s associated with Jobs and Developer Story. We’re in the process of creating a simpler flow that would allow users to export this data in one shot. We opted to share this post here earlier so that people had a heads-up that these changes were underway.

Comment: For those who don't want to wait till March for a JSON exporter, check out https://developerstory.dev - I built it to get my own data and figured others might get use from it too!

Comment: Buckminster Fuller is alleged to have said, "To change something, build a new model that makes the existing model obsolete.".   I think the are more than enough developers upset about these changes to build a better model of SO jobs. Let SO do their thing, band together and build a new one 

Answer (score 58):

The majority of the DMs I get on LinkedIn mention my SO developer story (specifically the Python top x%). I have freshers/juniors asking me how to get a good ranking on SO, motivated to start asking and answering questions on the platform!

I will not comment on the `JOBS` feature as I read both sides of it in the other answers and I honestly agree to both.

##### However, why remove the developer story?

- Wouldn't you want your users to "show off" their ranks, reputation, and profiles?
- Doesn't that help with attracting actual contributors to the platform and not just passerby's who need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> some code snippets (Guilty of this personally)?
- Isn't the point of all this gamification on the platform, including the reputation league, just to augment a coder's CV?

---

There are 3 links that I consider as my core market value in this coding community -

1. My Linkedin
2. My Github
3. My SO developer story

I would hate for it to go away without any plans of integrating the good elements of this tab into the user profile page! Please do consider those who have used the developer tab as a core part of their profile for so long!

Comment: +1000. Sunsetting Jobs is Stack Overflow business, and they can do as they see fit. But Developer SO story is *our* business.

Comment: *[Fresher](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fresher#Noun)* - *2. (India) A fresh graduate looking for one's first job*.

Comment: You have _"Top 0.1% Stack Overflow"_ in your LinkedIn profile... I'm not sure that's entirely honest, as even your developer story only lists you as top 1% in python?

Comment: It's an old update on my profile. I was 0.04% last year by December. Also, I am not sure why that is important. I read your comments on other answers (yes went through the majority of those), and I was wondering what your constructive thoughts on the issue above, rather than checking the validity of my linkedin profile :)

Comment: Also, the reason I linked the url was to have another portal for showing support to the issue but it seems I it would be better to not bias my answer with that.

Comment: I find it unfortunate that so many misguided companies have began relying on tag scores on a QA site as a measure of skill. Removing developer story will hopefully reduce that trend.

Comment: @KevinB - beg to differ! by your logic companies should ignore GitHub, because anyone could "fork" a repo and show it as their projects. By your logic, CV's should not even be a thing because you cant measure skill looking at a CV. You misunderstand; tag scores are not a measure of skill but a highlight on a CV. The true measure of technical skill can only be assessed (if at all) after someone has spent significant time working in an organization/team. Let's not mix up the 2 aspects here.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal github is difficult to fake. SO score is ridiculously easy to obtain. It's literally a game of quantity over quality. Post 10 answers a day, regardless of quality, and your rep will go up enough to be top 1% in a month. it's entirely meaningless.

Comment: Disagree again. It takes time and patience to get a reputation on SO. Its that time / effort that is valued here. Not one is saying one should judge how proficient someone is in a language by looking at SO reputation. But one CAN assess the passion, effort, time someone has put into the coding community as a measure of their reputation.

Comment: I agree on the quality of questions. But why would you gauge the quality of a skill from a Q&A site? That's not the point here though. Why not have someone show off their contribution to the community? When I show the answers I am proud of on my profile page, I want technical recruiters to see how I can summarize, explain, solve & articulate an answer to a question, regardless of the technical "quality" of the question. Some of the best-voted answers on SO are the most well-articulated answers to the simplest of problems that any coding toddler could solve.

Comment: Let me put this another way: What value, if any, does knowing that a potential future employee felt required to have a score on a Q&A site because they thought it'd help them get a job and therefore begrudgingly participated there to earn said rep?

Comment: What value did that person add to the Q&A community, by answering easy duplicated hundreds of times questions?

Comment: @KevinB - I mentioned a case in my above comment. It seems you are not only questioning the developer profile but the reputation system as a whole! I agree it's not perfect, but it is better than any other platform out there. The duplicate questions is definitely something SO needs to solve with better question matching. Right now their search is so bad that I have to use google to search SO questions to mark them as duplicate, rather than their own search! But thats a separate issue!

Comment: It is a separate issue, but having job prospects be influenced by meaningless numbers is certainly problematic. Even with my profile, I wouldn't want to work for a company that in any way used my SO reputation as a means to decide whether or not to consider me.

Comment: Anyways thanks for the constructive discussion. I do see where you are coming from but I only agree partially I guess. Spending time and effort on SO should be something that a person should be proud of, otherwise, you will be left with an almost dead platform where people only come to copy-paste code from :)

Comment: Also, anyone who is smart enough to consider SO as a hiring criteria should understand how the platform works in the first place (including its limitations). An example is my future employer (spoilers!) actually interviewed me on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65451045/cnn-model-conditional-layer-in-keras/65604874#65604874) that I wrote on SO as a dedicated 45 minute round. Thats an example of using the candidates SO profile the right way for hiring!

Comment: Yeah agreed. There's a new platform I found a few weeks back which looks promising on the dev story and jobs front (its only for devs from what I can see not sure about Testers etc) https://www.thefullstack.network

Comment: Thanks for this, will check them out!

Answer (score 56):

### A Eulogy to Careers 2.0

When [I joined Stack Exchange](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/08/09/please-welcome-jon-ericson-community-manager/), I got a bunch of [Careers 2.0](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/23/careers-2-0-launches/) swag. I used the cardboard Careers 2.0 coasters until they were completely stained with coffee rings and were thrown out. I just checked and my Careers 2.0 pen no longer writes. I didn't get the T-shirt, but something tells me it would be in threads by now. Such is life in a universe governed by [the second law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics).

The [original announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/23/careers-2-0-launches/) has not aged well either:

> One day, you’ll be telling your grandchildren about getting a programming job, version 1.0. You would send a “resume” to a “recruiter.” It included all kinds of silly information required by the esoteric resume ritual (foreign languages spoken, whether or not you play ultimate Frisbee, Microsoft-veteran status). This so-called “information” was utterly useless at determining whether you could program or not, but if you spelled everything right and used suitable fonts, you could come in for a day of interviews at which you would be asked to perform mundane programming tasks on a whiteboard.

Every time I've applied for a job (including at Stack Exchange), I've provided [my resume](https://jlericson.com/resume/). Joel was correct that it's "utterly useless at determining whether you could program or not", but resumes are still part of the hiring ritual and Stack Overflow failed at iconoclasm.

Why it failed is not a question I'm best suited to answer, but that won't stop me from trying. Shortly after I was hired at Stack Exchange I found out a good friend was interviewing programmers for his startup. So I asked him if he'd tried Stack Overflow's job listings. His answer was something like, "Sure, but it's really expensive. And we didn't get any good candidates, so we didn't renew." That was, more or less, the diagnosis I heard internally a few years later. Even in the new era of Careers 2.0, recruiters required resumes and Stack Overflow's service didn't provide enough of them.

It sure doesn't help that the job search market has been saturated with competitors lately. As an aside, have you seen the Indeed commercials featuring Major League pitchers [Mariano Rivera](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHvem3xEaTo) and [Max Scherzer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB7r3p-HLCM) coaching job applicants? It's all about humor and hope. There's barely any indication of what features Indeed brings to the table. Turns out most people are more interested in the idea that the right job is out there and that they can get it.

I will miss having [my CV on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/jericson). It's been helpful to have a place where I can keep a sort of career diary. Probably better if I keep it on my blog or [GitHub README](https://github.com/jericson) or (*shudder*) LinkedIn, but there's something nice about seeing I'm in the top 5% of answerers in Oracle. (Well, maybe I should highlight SQL instead.) No idea if it will help me get my next job, but it's fun to see.

When I was a programmer at Raytheon, a huge defense contractor, I used to dream of getting a job at some tiny upstart (say, Google). The idea that someone would see my Stack Overflow profile and offer me an exciting new adventure (as we are programmed to call our new jobs) was thrilling. The reality of getting offers out of the blue (including one from Google) doesn't feel so glamorous. Great opportunities don't get filled by recruiters cold calling (or rather, messaging) potential candidates. Desirable jobs, [in my experience](https://jlericson.com/2015/04/22/cs_females.html), get filled by qualified candidates without a lot of beating the bushes to flush them out.

I'm glad Stack Overflow eventually landed on Teams as the core revenue-generating product. While I have [a few misgivings about Collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413358/the-foundations-of-collectives-and-its-future/415268#415268), it's easier to see how the new products fit into the strengths of Stack Overflow. Careers 2.0/Talent/Jobs was a noble endeavor that never got pointed in just the right direction to succeed. There's nothing easy about [scaling a business without compromising core values](https://jlericson.com/2019/12/11/founders.html). That so many people worked so hard and for so long on what turned out to be a lost cause is, of course, discouraging. But there is honor in the struggle regardless of the results.

Comment: "_There's barely any indication of what features Indeed brings to the table._" But do they make you want to use Indeed? I mean, there's no better warrior-god playing than Max, the organ was hilarious, & I know which one is the [freaking pitching eye](https://thornescratch.tumblr.com/post/147175635228/i-love-you-max-scherzer-you-utter-weirdo), but have you seen the applicants Indeed churns out? Many are not top-shelf, self-screened, intrinsically motivated devs. I mean, maybe Apple, Google, and MS can convince us to apply by bombarding us, but didn't we already know if we wanted to work there?

Comment: @ruffin: I didn't use Indeed [when I was laid off](https://jlericson.com/2021/04/23/job_hunting.html), but in fairness I don't think they'd yet hit on the idea of using pitchers as pitchmen. My point wasn't that Indeed was better at providing candidates or even any good. Instead I was hoping to communicate that 1) they're trying to get more people to use the service as applicants and 2) there are tons of job search companies these days. I also think it's hilarious that Max Scherzer was between jobs, had 30 employers knocking on his door and he picked the Mets. Maybe not the best career coach.

Comment: "Desirable jobs, in my experience, get filled by qualified candidates without a lot of beating the bushes to flush them out."  How do these qualified candidates *find* the jobs in your experience?

Comment: I mean, I have gotten great opportunities by recruiter cold calls. I like *boring* companies, you all can fight over who gets the one exciting position at Google making the next thing they'll kill off in 2 years. I'm quite happy making a decent living doing interesting, practical things at companies people underestimate or forgot about.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects: Personal contacts mostly. Though thinking about it a bit more, I'm probably overstating it a bit because of my unique experiences.

Comment: @jrh Your work does _not_ sound boring. It appears you actually mean _lesser known_ . That makes more sense: one can often do more interesting work at lesser known since you have a wider impact within the company. A tiny piece of work at a huge company may affect more people but it's hard to "feel" that day to day.

Comment: Instead of wasting development efforts on the stupid filter feature which adds no value to end-users, you could’ve continued with the jobs and developer story. At least they were not useless.

Answer (score 48):

## Congratulations on posting the most downvoted question on meta — *ever!*

It is a great opportunity to remember the second most upvoted question *ever*: [I'm resigning as a Stack Overflow community elected moderator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390427/245183)

The departure of Stack Overflow's management's views and priorities from the needs and opinions of its very own community cannot be better demonstrated than by chopping off jobs and the developer story.

Truly ground-breaking!

Comment: +1 Extremely funny in an absurdly sad and enlightening sort of way. This answer deserves more votes.

Comment: As of right now (4/4/2022), I'm pretty sure this is the most downvoted question Stack Exchange has ever seen, on a meta site or otherwise.

Answer (score 47):

So, now that the only adequate and SPAM free job resource goes away, what are the alternatives? Surely, not LinkedIn, Glassdoor and all those other sites filled with fake positions leading to 3rd party, 3rd rate HR agencies.

What will you use from now on?

Comment: Probably connections in industry, if I were to be honest.  Or I may finally bite on one of those Amazon recruiter emails that I'm always getting.  More seriously, I want to assure you that just because Jobs is going way this doesn't mean that there isn't a way to find a job in tech anymore.  Jobs was definitely not the end-all be-all of technology or finding a tech gig.

Comment: @Makoto Yes, but it was a kinda of lighthouse, a ray of hope in the sea of irrelevance.

Comment: I think SO is the best place for REMOTE jobs. Even you can find alternatives they are more suitable for finding local jobs but not for remote ones. If you know any good resources for remote jobs please advise.

Comment: As a front-end web developer: build a portfolio website to showcase your work. As a back-end or any other software developer: showcase your work on GitHub and pick a decent template to build a portfolio website using a low-code tool like Webflow? Start technical writing on DEV.to.

Comment: More than half my professional career, now, has been at jobs I got -- easily -- through SO Jobs.  I guess next time I'll just spend weeks wading through spam instead.  Really sad :/

Comment: It's been only a couple of days, but Otta has been ok for me so far.  We'll see if it holds up.

Answer (score 43):

> While Talent & Jobs helped us get to where we are over the past decade, the talent acquisition space is not one where we have a strong competitive advantage. Developers, as you all know, don’t have a hard time finding job opportunities. The problem is often finding the right opportunity and job boards and sourcing are ineffective solutions. The effort it would take us to truly differentiate in this space is not one we could justify.

The way I see it, your competitive advantage is:

- You have one of the best-known online resources for developers. This makes it a natural destination for those who are looking for good developers.
- A lot of developers are already using the site to build a portfolio of sorts by posting answers that demonstrate their knowledge and their desire and ability to effectively share their knowledge. Letting them incorporate that into an online resume, and use that to find jobs, seems like a natural extension.
- You have an extensive tagging system to tell you what a question is about, and to allow you to effectively search for questions about any complex combination (involving union, intersection, exclusion, etc.) of topics. Even though you can't compete with search engines in terms of plain text searches, especially given that you haven't invested much into building up your search functionality, more complex searches can still sometimes be better on Stack Overflow (if you make good use of tags). The same system should, in theory, also allow for meaningful tagging and effective searching of both developers and jobs (and effective matching between them).
- You also have the Developer Survey, that allows you to get a good idea of what developers want (and those are the exact same developers who are using your platform). You can use this to improve Stack Overflow Jobs by adding or removing features in a way most useful to developers.
- You may have one of the most useful user feedback systems (in the form of Meta) that many companies would dream of having. SO staff isn't currently too active here, but if it's used well, it could help immensely with anything you build.

As for problems, I could probably summarise that as: the Developer Story. It groups all your experience and achievements into 1 sequential list. This goes against every recommendation for resume writing I've ever seen. It gives an answer I spent 10 minutes writing (if I deem it useful enough to list there) about the same prominence as a job I spent a few years doing (and the PluralSight tests are given higher prominence than everything else). I suppose it's supposed to be a *story*, but it makes it hard to easily see the different jobs someone has held, and for how long, and what education they have. But that's just one opinion, and I suppose there should be quite a few others who like the Developer Story.

Comment: The points you’ve described here are exactly how the Jobs platform functioned and why it was a major part of our strategy over the past decade. Unfortunately, traffic alone doesn’t cut it in the recruitment tech space; we lacked enough candidate engagement especially when compared to other competing products. Less than 1% of our monthly traffic engaged with Jobs and only ~0.03% have a Developer Story that’s visible to employers. (1/2)

Comment: These are solvable problems - for example, the suggestions you made about improving Developer Story are all valid. What we can’t justify is spending the time & effort needed to excel in this space compared to all the other things we could be doing. Our core isn’t tech recruitment and we would always lag behind others in the space that are solely focused on these problems. Making these changes allow us to spend more time improving our core knowledge sharing platform and the products that are closely aligned with it. (2/2)

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani So what changes can we expect from SO over the next few years as you free up resources and redirect them towards your core tech?

Answer (score 42):

Every job I've had in the last several years was due to a connection made on Stack Overflow.

Not from the Jobs product... but from directly interacting with like-minded folks when I answer their questions.

I probably would have used Jobs to find people myself, but the product was extremely expensive for smaller companies or for short term engagements.  I probably would have used Jobs to find a job, but the companies posting weren't often the type of companies I wanted to work for.

If you create a product along the lines of jobs/careers in the future, I hope that you do so in a way that can be used by more people, and for more types of gigs.  Stack Overflow needs better ways for humans to network together.

Comment: "_but from directly interacting with like-minded folks when I answer their questions._" I mean, elephant in the room, you also, um, have a SO rep of 150k. If I had a job in (checks profile) Node.js, php, or vanilla front-end work (*not* a put-down. We need so much more [vanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/)), you'd have to literally curse me to hell in an interview for me not to want to hire you, and I'd still likely try to do it even from hell, depending on what circle you put me in.

Comment: @ruffin Ha!  Well, amazingly the number of fake internet points don't actually mean much usually.  :-)  The people that contact me usually do so over a specific question or two.  The same goes for when I contact them.  I see your point though.

Comment: We considered & experimented with a self-serve option for Jobs aimed at smaller companies. However, this resulted in two major problems: 1) we had no way to monitor & manage the quality of listings being posted; 2) smaller companies typically posted 1-2 listings for a short duration (eg 30 days) which did not result in enough candidates for them to justify using the platform. In reality, most developers don’t actively seek out opportunities via job boards; they rely increasingly more on their network and connections, similar to your experience of interacting with like-minded folks.

Comment: @Punnet Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 42):

This is ridiculously short-sighted.

Financial decisions being made at this company are atrocious as they consistently miss the forest for the trees.

While Jobs may not have been as lucrative as other revenue sources at Stack Overflow, it served as a unique way to engage users, leading to user retention and content creation.

The only reason this place works is because of user engagement, and removing any aspect that will drop the group of actual experts interacting here should be seen as red hot don't touch.

Comment: _"Financial decisions being made at this company are atrocious as they consistently miss the forest for the trees."_ What do you _know_ about the financials involved in this decision? You're calling this shortsighted based on... What? Your perception of use of Jobs?

Comment: @Cerbrus A whole heck of a lot, and if you are curious about this conversation you may want to do some research before just wading in full force. Start here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY, and since you interested let's just cliff notes some highlights. $70M revenue: $44M Jobs, $16M Ads, $10M Teams. This was from April 2019 so it is a little dated, but still, it hasn't been all that long; clearly teams has grown since then. That said, it is clear that Jobs was a strong source of revenue, regardless of how necessarily profitable it was, it was a large source of user engagement.

Comment: The problem was that it didn't have the growth potential that other features had, and as a result they are shuttering it, even though it was so widely used that for a long time it was the primary source of revenue. I have had extensive conversations about this with Shog, Jon, Blufeet, and Jaydles about this over several years, and about revenue in general at Stack Overflow since 2017 or so. Unfortunately most of the people who actually know how this place works are gone, and there is a growing group of people now getting used to a new normal where a "community run environment" is a pipe dream.

Comment: Travis, that is a _lot_ of background information that's pretty crucial to this answer, which isn't exactly public/common knowledge. I've never ever heard of that YouTube channel, nor are we privy to whatever you discussed with those people. That's what my comment was about. This answer makes some claims... Correct or not, there's no information in it to back it up. TL;DR: Please cite your sources :D

Comment: That's fair, but I don't always have time to rehash half a decades worth of history in a post unfortunately, and perhaps I just assume too much common knowledge about some of the topics here.

Comment: One could call the Developer Story a 'loss leader', @Cerbrus  A loss leader doesn't make much money for a company and it might even run at a small steady loss. It is worth keeping though, due to synergistic effects without which profitable parts of the company would be subject to much less growth, revenue, profit, whatever.

Answer (score 38):

To save the story before it's removed, we've made https://www.getmanfred.com/stackoverflowgeddon, where you can export it as a JSON with an open source CV schema.

It's not the first "SO dev story exporter", but it tries to solve the problem where our CVs are tied to a specific service.

To avoid it, we currently allow users to synchronize their CV with GitHub, but there are plans in the near future to synchronize it with other platforms as well.

Comment: ¡It's nice! :).

Comment: It works like a charm - and the GitHub sync tool is awesome!

Comment: This solution is also mentioned here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416892/1654688, with alternative use of the opensource code build and shared by company Manfred https://getmanfred.com

Comment: And here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318637/export-resume-in-json-resume-format/416894#416894

Comment: Also I recently show this solution mentioned in the comments of another https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416704/1654688. Or in this other question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336029/how-can-i-export-the-developer-story-cv-as-markdown/416892#416892. And here: https://stackapps.com/a/9360/20382

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/9361/how-to-export-so-developer-story-to-an-standard-open-source-json-format/9362#9362

Comment: Only in Spanish? E.g., *"¿Te ha afectado el StackOverflowgeddon?. Recupera tu Developer Story en tan solo un click y mantenlo online (si quieres)"*

Comment: @PeterMortensen You can change the language in the top-right corner. But SO already removed access to the data time ago anyway

Comment: I didn't even get an email from SE about this, no chance to save my data.  Classy as always.

Answer (score 35):

This is a *huge* disappointment. SO Jobs has been a reliable, clear and easily parsable resource for job postings. Unlike many other sites, the structure, readability and general vibe of the postings was particularly suited to my expectations (and those of my other technical friends). Perhaps I have a naive view of how demanding the maintenance of Jobs is, but my feelings right now are along the lines of "shut up and just leave it alone". You mention finding it hard to be competitive against other sites. Well, is it a competition? Are a couple of abstracted metrics all you're interested in? In other words, do you prioritize quantity over quality? When I'm viewing job postings, I don't give a damn about "employer branding" or "company awareness". What I care about is:

- a no-bullshit description of what the job in question entails
- what the company does, so I can make an ethical choice
- a reasonably standardized posting format so I have a rough idea of what I can find there

I understand that SO is, in a very real sense, a business. But I've also (perhaps naively) thought that it was as much (or almost as much) about community. For a community the local perception of value of something like Jobs might be much more important than some global comparison with some external services. I must also say I'm rather put off by your attempts to euphemistically beat about the bush with expressions such as "sunset" or "competitive advantage". Perhaps I'm wrong in suspecting that deciding one way or another would make a difference to your finances, but my feeling is that at some point, somewhere in SO a bunch of managerial-type guys got together and started mumbling the usual biz-talk BS about "blah blah growth" and "blah blah next generation" without stopping for once to consider what the actual "blah blah community" finds good, useful and valuable. Sorry for being blunt, but I've seen that kind of sugar-coated talk too many times.

To summarize my rant, I have a couple of points TL;DR-style:

- You don't have to compete against the big players to be good. Jobs has certainly been good enough for thousands, maybe millions of people. Why take it away?
- If something is good (or good enough) it doesn't always mean you need to keep tweaking it. You don't have the resources to keep pushing it forward? Fine, maybe just leave it as is.
- If you *have* to make an unpopular decision, try not to sugar-coat it and sell it as a "benefit to the community". This might insult the intelligence of your users.
- A few honest words go a long way, as opposed to the same old generic template of how "we're so sorry, but...".

Answer (score 29):

Early in the morning waking up to hear this news is very heartbreaking and very sad news to me. I was online almost every day and trying to answer the questions just to increase points bit by bit. Which is very satisfying to me. As the more questions I answered I go to the TOP X%.

SO job listing had the jobs where any other big portals don't have those wonderful jobs. In fact, I got couple of job offers from SO from the countries where I couldn't imagine.

After this removal, where will the ***employers*** post their jobs? I know there are several many other portals. But to me, SO had the best job portal and had the perfect filters.

It's my wish that the **SO** should rethink this decision.

Comment: _"After this removal where will the employers"_ One of the hundreds of other sites out there?  Or just LinkedIn...

Comment: I have used several portal for jobs including LinkedIn. But none of them have the filters and labels with this much of clear information on the jobs posted.

Answer (score 27):

This is deeply disappointing. Stack Overflow was hands-down one of the best litmus tests I had for employers. When I was contacted by a recruiter, or I decided to reach out to them, I would send along my SO Developer Story. If they countered with "we also need a resume" then I *knew* they didn't pay enough attention to "where developers spend time, get questions answered, and build community." That was enough to tell me they wouldn't value me as a developer in the ways I needed, and I moved on.

Losing this basic litmus is painful. I'm sure glad the new owners have decided that their bottom line and "inability to differentiate themselves in some ill-defined marketing category" is more important than the value the actual community has found in the tools we've been given.

My honest hope is that someone builds an opt-in SO Dev Story alternative. Poll the APIs, build out the stats, and recompile the most relevant points, plus-or-minus some functionality to customize. Seems like a great opportunity, one I wish I had spare cycles for.

Comment: can we have alternatives ? so far I found flowcv.io and jsonresume.org, SO was the best place for having fresh CV, sad.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil I created [devstory.fyi](https://devstory.fyi?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social) with an [import feature](https://devstory.fyi/users/story/preview?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social) that will allow you to migrate and continue managing your story. Let me know what you think!

Comment: looks like a nice service, but must say I decided to not use any of cv services anymore. safer to keep private.

Answer (score 26):

Please don't remove the Job listing. There are many who is really trusting SO Job and developer story which would be hard once the deprecations.

Answer (score 25):

Removing Jobs from the portal would reduce the gamification of the site, resulting in fewer people answering questions, which would in turn reduce the value of the Q&A aspect of the site too.

Comment: [Citation needed]. Plenty of users are grinding out rep just fine, whilst ignoring the fact Jobs exists.

Comment: Can confirm - my gamification of the site in the mid-2010s didn't slow down a tick because of the existence of Jobs.  It's slowed down for more obvious reasons in later years, though.

Comment: jobs didn't exist when i was most driven by the gamification. Jobs being added only annoyed me.

Comment: None of the Jobs features affect rep & privileges on the site. It was intentionally designed to be separate from Q&A

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani The loss of the "top %" section on Developer Story is most likely the reduction in gamification that Zesty is referring to here, and it's something I agree on - part of my SE engagement was driven by the desire to narrow that percentage and put forward that developer story as part of my applications for developer roles, showing those numbers off. Without Dev story my attention while on SE may move off to more hobby related sites.

Answer (score 24):

It's simply sad to read so many comments like "I got my first job thanks to this", "I got my current role with SO", knowing what a loss it will be for the people to come and won't have that opportunity. I'm not one of them, but I've searched the job listing occasionally because of things like transparent salary, Joel test and current employers integration with their own SO accounts.

While it looks demanding from "our" side, this site is what it is thanks to the people who use it and answer all the questions. 99,9% of them are simply non-affiliated people that use their time moderating and answering issues of other developers.

The explanation, at least for me, made no sense either. It does not explain, with words a regular user can understand, what are the next steps. Other than SO as a company does not want to maintain the job postings anymore.

Comment: Next steps? There are no next steps other than shutting down jobs, as you can read under _"What can you expect in the coming months?"_

Comment: I agree I got my first gig off here a few years back...sad....although a new platform I found a few weeks back which looks promising on the dev story and jobs front (its only for devs from what I can see not sure about Testers etc) https://www.thefullstack.network

Comment: Probably the management has looked at profit margins over at LinkedIn etc. and decided that it will be more profitable to take a slice of that cake, for instance by selling them ads. Hence the next announcement was https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416964/the-future-of-our-jobs-ad-slots?cb=1 .

Answer (score 21):

Well, now more of a feature suggestion, but can you all take the good bits of the CV, Developer story and move them into the profile? Letting people tell other people who they are is core part of community building.

I ask this as someone who was using their SO Jobs profile as the canonical source of resume information, and now I guess I have to go back to [USAJobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USAJobs) or notepad or something.

Comment: What is "[notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_(disambiguation))"? Do you mean [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Notepad)? Or some online notepad? If yes, which one? Something else?

Comment: I mean Notepad.

Comment: I second this request. I have used my developer story as my resume for the last decade or so, to great success. Its great to be able to tell a recruiter "my resume is hosted on SO, here is a link:" 
Losing the dev story is a big personal loss for me.

Comment: Third. 87654321

Answer (score 18):

SO Jobs got a lot of my face time since I spend a lot of time on the site. I'm a bit surprised the company could not make it work financially given the opportunity to gain the attention of so many serious developers. Also I did not find the postings annoying: it did not turn me off from the site.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you didn't find the posts intrusive, we spent a lot of time trying to strike a good balance between promoting relevant content and not being disruptive. Check out [the comments I posted here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415408/6518788), it's related to this topic.

Answer (score 18):

It's sad to see Developer Story disappearing. I've used the PDF version of my developer story in all of my applications. Also I used to check my rank in top tags from Developer Story but I guess that's available from other parts of SO.

Comment: `Also I used to check my rank in top tags from Developer Story but I guess that's available from other parts of SO` It is not available from other official part of SO

Comment: :( @PanagiotisBougioukos

Comment: I agree although I haven't really used it (didn't feel confident just yet) although I did find a new platform I found a few weeks back which looks promising on the dev story and jobs front (its only for devs from what I can see not sure about Testers etc) https://www.thefullstack.network

Answer (score 17):

Honestly, I never understood the Developer Story, probably because there's no indication that anybody ever looks at them other than the users putting theirs together.  It's also an odd layout that doesn't take into account an absence of work on Free Software projects or different lengths of time, but these are tinier quibbles.

Jobs, though, while I have issues with Stack Overflow Jobs--only remembering the most recent cover letter and not requiring a consistent application experience, for examples---the postings have still been significantly higher quality than any other job board that I've seen.  And the recruiters requesting my application have been the *only* recruiters to treat me like more than a search result.

So, the idea that the company would rather "leverage our unique position to solve real, meaningful problems for our users and customers" to corporate branding than helping developers rings false.  Likewise, if ditching large features without soliciting opinions is the new way forward, *maybe* "building communities" isn't actually a core strength?

I mean, it's the parent company's company, and clearly they like using vocabulary like "leverage" and "core strength" more than they like the return on investment of the Jobs service.  But this still seems like the wrong way around things, when a plain-talking "this doesn't bring in enough money to warrant the developer hours involved" would have been less jarring to the community.

Comment: Same. It was extremely misleading to receive an email notification about Developer story going away while the much bigger news was the removal of Stackoverflow Jobs.

Answer (score 13):

[Careers 2.0](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/23/careers-2-0-launches/) provided a vision for the future of recruitment.
What is Stack Overflow's vision of the future of recruitment at the moment?

Does Stack Overflow have a vision of recruitment at this moment or is it no longer part of the company strategy?

Comment: It is no longer part of our strategy

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Comment: @PuneetMulchandani is the users engagement which happened in the past part of the new strategy in SO? Could you please kindly check for this reason my answer on how this may affect the users engagement in terms of motivation for contribution?

Answer (score 10):

It would be better if you surveyed your users and decided with their company. I expected you to respect your user more.

Comment: Not exactly a Great Expectation, yet that hasn't been happening of late...

Answer (score 8):

Are you kidding. You have the most trustworthy developer job-seeking platform on the entire internet and you're just going to ditch it!?

Answer (score 7):

It's the best feeling when you are desperately trying to look something up for your work on Stack Overflow, and then you get hit with a great looking job offer. I never applied for a job, but it really felt great.

Comment: Great looking job offers are all over the place on all kinds of sites. Heck, even on LinkedIn  I get plenty of great offers. "It feels good" isn't a practical reason to maintain something like jobs, though.

Answer (score 7):

This is what they meant with:

> Prosus is an investment and holding company, which means that the most important part of this announcement is that Stack Overflow will continue to operate independently, with the exact same team in place that has been operating it, according to the exact same plan and the exact same business practices. Don’t expect to see major changes or awkward “synergies”.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, we made & shared this decision back in early 2021, which was well before we were acquired. This has been years in the making.

Answer (score 7):

As an extensive user of the platform, IMHO, It made perfect sense to have a job board as part of the SO platform. Sad to see this go.

Answer (score 7):

> The Advertising components of our Talent offering, specifically focused on Employer Branding.

The most saddest thing I ever read on internet nowadays.

StackOverflow was one of the few companies who focused not only on Employer Branding but on Employee Branding too. It provided a very nice and handy interface to make my presence outstanding by providing a possiblity to share not only my job experiences and interests and bla-bla but giving an insight about how I communicate with strangers and how helpful I could be in my field of interests.

I could not say any other job listing site that could provide this feature. Github is trying to achieve similar thing (branding employees), but it's a whole different approach and does not fit if you are not a Developer but a DevOps, SysAdmin, etc.

I absolutely understand, we, employees aren't so wealthy to support this kind of services but honestly, it could be harder and harder to outstand from the mass. The IT is overcrowded and you have to fight quite hard to be recognized. If you are on the beginning on your career path... well, good luck.

Comment: _"The IT is overcrowded and you have to fight quite hard to be recognized. If you are on the beginning on your career path... well, good luck."_ ... What? Recruiters are literally begging developers to work for them, there's a massive shortage of developers, worldwide... It's not at all hard to get a job in IT.

Comment: I agree with Gabor, that it isn't easy at all to get recognized, and to get a decent job in IT if in the beginning of one's career. This is especially true if one is not a "Rock Star Developer" (sigh...).

Answer (score 7):

I was using Developer Story as my primary résumé. I liked the template so much and will miss it.

Answer (score 7):

From the other side, as an almost-would-be-customer, I can only say the only reason we as a company never used it was that [it was literally easier to find out how much it would cost to send a printed copy of the listing into geosynchronous orbit than finding out how much it would cost to list it here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352029/1843468).

I was not able to justify spending the time to find out. Boss wanted to know what it costs, and the only thing I could find was "talk to us to find out". If I need to fill out a whole form and talk to a sales representative on the phone just to get an estimate on the cost, it's too complicated for a small team. I'm convinced it would've gotten better results than what the recruiter services we later on hired dug up, but "no information" was a big red flag to my boss.

So maybe, just maybe, next time tell me what to expect, then I might use it, and it will "get some traction".

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's time to turn off the automated email that prompts us to update the developer story?

> "Have you built something new, contributed to open source projects, or changed jobs? We noticed that you haven’t updated your Developer Story in a while."

Comment: It's in the works, it'll happen as part of the changes we're making in February

Answer (score 6):

No.. Please don't end the job Board.
You guys have the best job board and its a one stop destination for budding developers like me

Answer (score 6):

In my eyes SO is stopping doing what it should be doing.  They are doing more and more actions for themselves.

I think connecting developers with companies that need them is one of the perks being on SO as a helpful developer.

The main question is: "**What has now SO to offer for the developers that dedicate their time helping others**?" Points? (Useless)  Good feeling?  That is true, but it should offer more and I'm afraid this is beginning of the end for SO in the long run.

For me, I can say it was nice while it lasted.  I'll visit only those tags I care about and use SO even less now.

Comment: No, the core is still a repository of high-quality answers to non-redundant actual questions that software developers have (OK, a first-order approximation. It is difficult with [22,216,614 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions), a company that doesn't care about quality (the measured stuff is all about quantity), the [ongoing Eternal September](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/), and gamification that favors [*fast* answers over *comprehensible* answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19533)). Jobs was always a side show - a way to monetise the core.

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes that (high-quality questions and answers) is the core, I think we agree on that.  The difference in opinion here is: "How to you motivate developers to provide high quality answers/questions?" You could improve on *Jobs* on SO, no doubt about it.  Getting rid of it altogether is a huge mistake.  I know it was a way to monetize the core, but also it served a purpose to interconnect two seeking parties.  Only the future will show, but I really do think this is beginning of the end.

Answer (score 6):

Completely exiting the space is the wrong decision from a growth standpoint. I see a lot of mistakes being made by Stack Exchange that look good on paper lately but are bad in practice, this is just one more.

Developer story was one of the drivers for me to participate on SE. A link to that page was included with every job application I sent out over the past several years, I considered the PluralSight IQ badges and the top % on SE badges an asset to showing my abilities to potential employers and worked to improve those numbers, landing me in the top 20% on two technologies and the top 10% on a third. While I don't have that need anymore now that I have permanent employment, there are others in the same boat.

Just because a product isn't directly making you much money, or because you are not a leader in the field doesn't mean it is something that should be cut. Retail has long understood this premise, that's why they hold sales, offering products that will get people in the door so they can make money on the other things those people buy. Perhaps these features are one of Stack Exchange's "sales" something that draws users even if it's not the thing the company profits on when the users are here.

Answer (score 6):

Since Stack Overflow Jobs announced is shutting down, I've decided to build a curated list of **alternatives**.

I hope it helps lots of developers to find a job

*[Stack Overflow Jobs Alternatives](https://www.stackoverflowjobsalternatives.com/)*

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I was going to ask about how I could opt out of this feature earlier this month since I didn't want it anymore at all, but it slipped my mind...

Ultimately I think this is a good thing.  Despite its heralding as a revolution to job searching, I've used it exactly twice in my professional career and walked away disappointed both times.  One company ghosted me.  Another *cold call* interviewed me and expected me to just "be ready" for them.  No intro, no nothing - just - let's go into this SQL and dive right in.

For someone who was three years into their career, that's something I've carried with me ever since - to not be like *those* jerks.

And this was quite some time ago - probably back in 2015, 2016 era.  I don't recall there being a lot of opportunity to give feedback on how this actually was doing, and I don't really recall the company being particularly ...*open*...to feedback on the service.

But this is still a good thing.  Glad to see this one go.

Comment: As a matter if interest, when you were cold called and expected to to participate in an an interview,  _what did you do_?  Perhaps  acquiesce,  and participate,  push back, withdraw,  or something else?

Comment: @chrisneilsen:  I went through it.  I mean, three years in the industry, what did I know about this?  It definitely was different to the first/only time I had been interviewed, which was introductory, then a walkthrough of what to expect, some time to prepare, then the actual thing - nope, this was some senior dev asking me a whole bunch of SQL questions for a Python job.  Go figure.

Comment: I had a similar experience with an employer working in an area as I also did before. He therefore probably felt that I might know something more than what I already did at my previous employer (exactly what his coders did to his own project) he completely disregarded my CV, to say the least .... It was like, well, we repair cars here, but as time as you already master this craft, let's see if we can make together a plane instead. That was very awkward considering that I had already managed to work as a full stack at a project similar to his own

Answer (score 5):

OMG! SO is the rightest place for job ads for developers. I always considered SO job ads as more professional than other platforms.
You asked yourself:

> how can we leverage our unique position to solve real, meaningful
> problems for our users and customers?

then came up with removing Jobs!!!?

Is Microsoft going to acquire LinkedIn or create another platform?

Comment: ...you *do* know that happened a while ago, right?  I legit can't tell if you're being facetious or just clueless on this front, since it was pretty big news at the time.

Comment: *"[LinkedIn ... Since December 2016, it has been a wholly owned subsidiary of Microsoft.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn#Acquisitions)"*

Comment: Oh I didn't know that !

Comment: Yeah M$ already own LinkedIn, they don't care about any particular vertical. There's a new platform I found a few weeks back which looks promising on the dev story and jobs front (its only for devs from what I can see not sure about Testers etc) https://www.thefullstack.network

Comment: Right. Honestly feels like this has mba’s written all over it - people who don’t understand the ethos of the development community.

Comment: Nah, don't blame MBAs @technogeek1995 An MBA who got any knowledge at all from his education would realize that it makes sense to keep Developer Story and SO Careers. That's because SO Jobs are a type of 'loss leader' (as I learned during my MBA program). Loss leaders might make little money for a business, or even lose money, but they are well worth the cost and staff resources. That's because the presence of a loss leader has beneficial synergistic effects on highly profitable parts of the company that wouldn't be possible otherwise.

Comment: @EllieKesselman I think you're being ironic, but just for others coming across this comment: SO has the world's best loss leader: its Q&A platform. It doesn't need another one. Jobs was meant to make money.

Answer (score 5):

Probably at such news some smart people here will try to ***scrape the Jobs API*** (despite of myself being not sure if such thing actually exists here) in order to save for their future use some companies details. It's not a good decision for SO to trash such a gold mine. Even worse, you just plan to empty a place that it was so comfortably filled by yourself. If you leave that space (of offering jobs) almost instantly some competitors can come to take over that market share that you carelessly abandon.

Second thing that probably will happen is that, being (like so many successful platforms out there) an *user - created content* platform, many people will leave massively the platform because of it transforming itself from an '*almost-work environment*' toward something more '*almost-fun environment*'. The core of SO success was to always help people be more productive (not just at their actual workplaces but also at a personal level, in their quest to advance in a career).

If your management staff thinks that users gain too much value and want instead to collect much more for the platform itself, that would be harder if losing the users interest to stay here.

I imagine that after staying 6-8 hours daily on SO to either answer or write questions it was a refreshing thing (almost as an award) to be able to also see some job offers in the same webpage. ***Let's not forget that people actually WORK while being here, it's not just as easy as reading the news!*** I congratulate the exquisite efforts of those answering with truly elaborate posts to various edge scenarios questions, and also the effort of those asking valid things (after reading tons of posts in that topic before daring to write original new questions - to avoid duplication and stay relevant).

Jobs section was [ is ]  something as a prize for many of those capable fellows which in return are coming again (even after succeeding to find a good job) to even learn more, ask more, answer even more.

What is the best thing of all is that **browsing SO while at work isn't considered something bad**. Browsing SO isn't NSFW (not suitable for work)! Instead is a good thing to be among the top ones, to search the best solutions to the problem at hand, to even answer to some others after you did find yourself some solution by your own as a give back.

What is Twitter for instant news is SO for instant solution at many topics (well, if you want to keep it as it is).

And, don't worry, the best advertising and promotion for the companies is the very fact that they are here as employers, offering Jobs content, because :

- it shows they are expanding (therefore they have a vision, and are financially sound)
- it shows they care for communities (because they are in search for new people to hire them - instead of just outsourcing their needs or buying from other companies around)
- nobody would be as interested in company branding as this new policy thinks (I hope you have heard the words saying that *nobody cares how much you know before they know how much you care* and also that *you can't impress someone of whom you don't really care*). This is because companies aren't as much interested to just brag like "look how good and big we are" as much as increasing their bottom line and making profits. We all know how narcissistic each company can be :) and also the people at times. Despite of many users being here to also build a nice prestige for themselves (which keeps being harder and harder because top questions were almost told all of them - or already answered, and answered well - in many areas), that would be useless if they wouldn't have deep pockets viewers to award their efforts (not just with upvotes but with real jobs).

My conclusion thus stays the same as the general one, and I would say it in a Yoda style: "*where you are, well you are*".

And even more: **Why try to fix something that ain't broken at all ?**

================

**Later edit**: *I read answers from a lot of people about being "sad" - it's useless to just be sad while you could instead **use some RSS reader (for example the free one - Inoreader) and save the feed link** from bottom side of Jobs list page in it - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/feed) - so you have the solution.*

*Therefore, you can have stored all companies and all their present job offers, plus the new ones starting from now, for the future (just in case these companies will expand their talent pool - but who doesn't? - and continue to hire - or simply just change part of their staff when not performing, resigning or changing career). Probably the most useful thing though is to keep on your records the specific `tech stack` that these companies use - and align your skills through education (plus what you build as a solid portfolio) to their stack for the future.*

Answer (score 5):

**Developer Profile is a medium to show one's contribution and get a sense of satisfaction.**

I know a lot of people who use their SO Developer Profile in their CV.
By removing the developer profile feature, the company is undermining the effort of all SO Community members which make the useful position of SO today.

I am totally disappointed by this, although my contribution is less.

The job section of SO is less cluttered and I recommend a lot of my friends to use SO for their *job application*.

**The above two features are a catalyst for contributions on SO. It’s really sad that these two features will be removed from here.**

Answer (score 5):

Sad. SO is the only place I like looking for jobs and I point to my Developer Story in every job I apply to. I think it's a clear indication of profits over people, and ironically, this will likely diminish returns in the long run as fewer developers and small companies use the site.

I personally don't use Stack Overflow anymore except for occasional references to things I've forgot. When I do I always glance at the Jobs section just to see what positions are posted. You're doing a great disservice to the developer community - the ones that lifted you up and made you what you are - in the short-sighted interest of profits.

Community-driven websites that try to take something given in fairness for free and squeeze extra profits from of at the expense of said masses are destined to fail if they slight the ones that made them. [Quora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quora) charging for answers, SO removing a beneficial feature for something none of us want.. I'll see you fellas with [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) and [Ask Jeeves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask.com)!

Comment: What do you use instead of Stack Overflow?

Comment: Well, at least we got [an evergreen meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-is-babby-formed).

Answer (score 5):

Computing science is the most demanded qualified profession in the world and you want to end up with jobs section of one of the most visited site about computing science? You have a lot of software programmers registred in your website and you aren't making money with all the companies searching for programmers? I can't understand it.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly trying to figure out if this is an elaborate April fool's day prank or publicity stunt. My experience over the years is completely at odds with the "forward looking" statement about having trouble differentiating. SO jobs had such a lower signal to noise ratio and higher quality than most of what I found elsewhere. Maybe it wasn't profitable in the way hoped for, or that generational differences complicated the market. There were a lot of synergies in how the site funtioned that has made it an internet institution. I hope to be wrong, but this seems like the beginning of the end for this site if true.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a prank. April 1st is a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion SO jobs was probably the best tool for developers to find a new job. To give you a sense of what I'm talking about, because I was answering a lot of Angular, [NgRx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/) and [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) questions 5 or 6 years ago, randomly at some point while searching myself for a question on SO I noticed a job ad on the side. For a 25 years old French guy, sending a resume to a startup in central London seemed as crazy and unlikely thing to happen. Guess what? It worked out and I've been working for that company for 4.5 years now.

I got to live in central London for 2.5 years which was beyond amazing in so many ways and now I keep working for that company remotely as I came back living in France. But what a ride it's been so far! I know this could've happened probably with a different job ad on LinkedIn or somewhere else. But it didn't and  it's the Stack Overflow one that made it happen. I mentioned that countless times to HR too, so that they could keep using SO for job ads. I'm really really sad to see this feature go away.

Now on the developer story. I didn't find that thread randomly. I was about to add a new open source project I just published on GitHub and [NPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Npm_(software)) to my developer story. I searched it for a solid 5 minutes in my profile thinking that the UI probably got modified a bit. Until at some point I just thought it was probably gone for some reason... And here we are. What a sad day. I **loved** that story. I was writing every small success there, and it was such a neat timeline to remember what I was proud of. It was a great place to aggregate all the open source repositories I published, YouTube videos, blog posts I wrote, jobs I got, etc. This was my one source of truth to assemble all this thing across time. I really wish I had a notification or an email giving me a warning because I'd have taken a screenshot or saved it somehow. Now it's just gone.

Please Stack Overflow, reconsider your choice for both the jobs and the developer story. These two things are absolutely amazing.

Answer (score 4):

Having opened *Stack Overflow* to check and answer on some question, a banner caught my attention and **for a second I felt excited for it thinking that it was for a new feature release...** poor me, it was totally the opposite and it showed up to be a deprecation note for a feature I loved so much!

The *Developer Story* and *Job Search* were more than features, but more of a unified space that helped me keeping hope to see a more natural and human friendly space where developers can come to find their next big thing.

Money has always and will always be the reason behind despair...

Answer (score 4):

This is only comparable to YouTube removing the dislike count.

Makes you wonder about how management decision are made and how disconnected people in companies get about what people thinks / expects from their product(s)

Comment: How is this related? YT removing dislikes is just to protect a certain portion of the community from negative attention. Noble as it may be, though misguided... Removing jobs is a financial decision, it doesn't consider users, it's just statistics.

Comment: YT removing dislikes is to engage people in the comments; the uploader already had the option of disabling likes/dislikes count. Therefore it is also a financial decision (it is always about the money)

Comment: Uploaders never had the option to -only- disable dislikes. This movement to hide all signs of negativity is something that’s been over the internet the last few years. Even SO tried it for a while, but it just doesn’t solve the issue it is meant to solve… It’s purely to prevent people from getting their feelings hurt, and that’s in no way related to this jobs removal.

Comment: Disabling dislikes and comments was a good enough protection against harassment. Disabling ONLY dislikes count is for engagement (imho). I don't get the added value of disabling dislikes count vs the previous situation.

Comment: Disabling dislikes is dishonest. Then a +1k -11k video suddenly shows only +1k...

Comment: Ιsn't the same now? A video may have been crappy and downvoted by the whole community but you still have to SPEND TIME on the platform to see for yourself. So it ends up being about staying there more.

Comment: We're getting a little off-topic, here. Of course, _in the end_, everything is about money. But then we might as well be complaining they shouldn't be approving new Area51 sites, because it's "all about the money"...

Comment: :+1 yes I agree on your last point

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly the case when the amount of downvotes (or upvotes) doesn't change anything - they do what they want to do no matter how many people are frustrated and disappointed here.

Comment: It's an _announcement_, not a discussion...

Comment: If it's an announcement you should remove any voting, any comments, and answers.

Answer (score 4):

There is always a decision which takes you 5 years ahead or 5 years back. And in this case I think it takes SO 5 years back. Such a disappointment to remove these features. This corporate shift move will cost more than just revenue.

Answer (score 4):

Going through the answers and comments, I see many people are going to miss the features that are marked to be dropped.

As far as the job advertisements go, I also would like to see more targeted ads than some random generic ads.

Developer stories enabled people to be visible to the relevant people.

Having said that, I totally understand this move and what I'm about to write down below **may not be the most popular opinion**.

The question that I would ask myself is "what do I really expect from Stack Overflow?". The first things that come to my mind is definitely not:

a) To make myself visible to the world

b) To find a job

As per my understanding, Stack Overflow's original intention has been basically to provide a Q&A platform for professional and enthusiast programmers. Which they certainly did a good job with.

But, it’s not only the Stack Overflow, is it? Stack Overflow is based on the Stack Exchange community platform which facilitates many other industries and people in different careers. I don't really understand who's concerned about which part of the platform, but I do understand managing many specialized features on a single common platform is a disaster in the making. It is not good for the basic product and the concerns.

This decision in my eye is a step towards the right direction. Yes, it would take away the features that some are really fond of. But, it will keep the platform running for many years to come.

If you miss a feature, build something yourself and open it to the world. Who knows if it can become the next [LinkedIn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn)? Maybe Stack Overflow people should get together and make one improving on their experience. I don't know how, but whatever that works will work.

### Side Note

Remember the good old days of Facebook when it was just a place where friends met up and made sense. Then the apps and games came through which we enjoyed. I don't remember when came what, but, pages and groups also came through and everyone and their dog wanted to become a Facebook personality.

They started to collect all your data and push towards you all the information that you really don't want. Eventually it became a site filled with features and information that stands in your way. It has grown too far to a point that they can no longer manage it properly, resulting several large scale data breaches. Therefore, in the recent years people started to move away from Facebook as its goals changed and turned into a "in your face" kind of a platform.

I'm certain that there were people who enjoyed all those features. But, they did help the platform to deviate from its original calling and become **not** the post popular social network in the world.

Comment: The Jobs part of this site was (and still is) totally optional; unlike Facebook tracking. I do not think this is a step in the right direction at all.

Comment: Re *"build something yourself and open it to the world"*: There is [an ongoing attempt](https://forum.codidact.org/c/new-site/6) [for the non-jobs part](https://forum.codidact.org/t/what-are-we-trying-to-build/27/109)

Comment: And [kfir88 is interested in acting on it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story/415857#415857).

Comment: [g.d.d.c also mentioned it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story/415734#415734) (at the end).

Comment: [Tobias Kienzler is a volunteer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415588/).

Answer (score 4):

Please give SO back to Jeff; this is a decision made by business people for business people, not by developers to developers.

I hope you get to regret this decision the same way [Experts-Exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experts_Exchange) (among others) had to regret their shady knowledge gating and practices towards a free and open space to gain knowledge, provide it, or merely get relevant information.

I know for sure I'll be contributing *a lot less* to Stack Overflow and the network in general, as most of the time I'm helping people in [chat](https://t.co/I0ktfRV9hT) or answering questions about Android or Linux (but had my fair time helping macOS users back then).

Comment: Jeff Atwood is still thinking about Stack Overflow and what it ought to become. E.g., ["Help me"* is *not* the purpose of Stack Overflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsvgSBGdpt0&t=5m52s), [Stack Overflow is more like Wikipedia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZz2Rr5qFuQ&t=12m50s), and *"[...some of the leadership, has kind of lost touch with the community.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jurlnqqWKA&t=37m40s)"* Also, [he is not going to have sex in public](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsvgSBGdpt0&t=41m30s). Aha! But he actually said that.

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qsvgSBGdpt0) [is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NGdarWF6rto) [a](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jurlnqqWKA) [list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZz2Rr5qFuQ) [of](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkbkFqbBZ3c) [interviews/talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koPhpmPYOxk) [in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubYRFW7SASI) [public](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhYQms3QF3o), [2017](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbsACrtT9h0) - [2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEJ6ptj9Ljg), [in reverse chrono order](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq9YhwLdqWI).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have seen most of these and it kinda confirms what I mean: this is a knowledge base for the masses related to (SO specifically) developing software. Jobs is an instrumental part in how people writing software makes a living; with an industry saturated by bad players, and practices, SO Jobs is/was a breath of fresh air, at least giving some transparency where it mattered.

Answer (score 4):

One of the things I don't like about LinkedIn, where I've done so much of my job searching, is that I can't seem to lay my projects out in a sensible way. Stack Overflow really allows programmers to tie their experience to actual specifics in a way that other job boards just don't.

On the other hand, SO has to think about where to put resources just like any other company/organization. The job marketplace has so many big players already and I have to trust that SO has done the cost/benefit analysis in terms of whether to continue in this space.

Answer (score 4):

I am a developer and recruiter.

The problem with SO jobs is it is extremely overpriced at $500/per ad and not accessible to any advertiser.

The ads should be $50 each and anyone should be able to place an ad - including recruiters.

Comment: But then the signal-to-spam ratio would go down(?).

Comment: Not so sure it would, it was mostly spam already.

Comment: @KevinB I disagree; it was very good from my perspective.

Answer (score 4):

The reason many people object to sunsetting the stackoverflow jobs:

Most people who read this thread are those people who clicked a job link and then found the notice that the SO jobs will be discontinued. Instinctively, they tend to criticize this.

The SO jobs are obviously inconsistent with the mission of SO as a Q&A knowledge sharing website.

Comment: If you open SO's front page without being logged in, you'll see that it sees itself as more than just a sole "Q&A" website. For example, the site's title: `Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers`. I think SO Jobs fit in there pretty well.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, Jobs take **huge** part of the right sidebar in its advertisements:

[image: sidebar with Jobs ad]

What will you put there instead?

Comment: Probably the bit of the jobs product that remains, advertising.

Answer (score 4):

I created [devstory.fyi](https://devstory.fyi?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social) with an [import feature](https://devstory.fyi/users/story/preview?utm_campaign=launch&utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=social) that will allow you to migrate and continue managing your story.

You can import and fully manage your story. You can share (if you want) a public url. You can also download your data in **JSON resume** format without creating an account. See steps outlined in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/416753/823967).

Comment: Hi! Interesting idea! How about you open a separate meta question about this, and maybe we can get a mod to [featured] it, drawing more users' attention to it, as the dev story closing is drawing nigh.

Answer (score 4):

For those wanting to save their story we have created a solution for you. [filenewjob.com](https://www.filenewjob.com) is now live and you can import your story into it. FileNewJob will be a job board similar to what you've used before but with some changes and improvements to what is/was available here and elsewhere.

It's an idea we were kicking around for a while and following this announcement by Stack we thought we'd better get on with it. So, until the end of March, when you create an account on FileNewJob you will have the option to enter the URL for your public SO story; we'll import that and convert it to a FileNewJob journey which you can then add and amend as you want.

Don't worry that some of the features aren't all available yet, they are coming, we just wanted to give you all as much time as possible to #SaveYourStory.

Answer (score 3):

Well this really, really sucks. Any chance you'll permit the community to continue running this on their own instead? I volunteer.

Comment: Uh, no. Don't think so.

Comment: Heck no. I don't want some random user getting all out PII.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well obviously with some sophisticated zero knowledge mechanism...

Answer (score 3):

> **Developer Story will be leaving Stack Overflow**

> On April 01, 2022,
> Stack Overflow will no longer support Developer Story. You can
> download a copy of your existing Developer Story as a PDF if you wish
> to retain this information.

If that is your april fool day, it is not funny. Hope that is not a technique to see what the reactions are and say, if community is largely against it, that it was a joke.

(I suspect you guys at Prosus are able to think like that)

Answer (score 3):

Found my First Job Via SO Jobs.

More often Innovative Startups would have detailed listings about a Position.

Sad to see it go

Answer (score 3):

SO Jobs is the only place where you can find Job listing where Visa Requirements are clearly mentioned and you can find jobs across the whole world in one place. It is very tough to fathom that such an innovative feature will no longer be available to us.

Answer (score 3):

According to OP Puneet Mulchandani, the majority of Stack Overflow company leadership and staff have concluded that,

> job boards and sourcing are ineffective solutions [and] the effort it
> would take us to truly differentiate in this space is not one we could
> justify.

In fact, you ***have*** truly differentiated yourselves in this space! (I humbly suggest that job boards **are** rather effective solutions for discovering employment opportunities). But I do realize that there may be significant costs involved in sustaining Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story. You tried for over five years, and created a wonderful resource which is superior to [LinkedIn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn), [Dice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice.com), [Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeed), and anything else I can think of.

I would understand if Stack Exchange wanted to get out of the talent search business entirely, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Your new Talent initiative intends to bring developer tools to developers, while engaged in answering questions on Stack Overflow. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/6XtwS2Ju76Y) conveys that message pleasantly, for the most part.

As for branding... I don't know. The CEO of Stack Exchange says, emphasis mine,

> We are realigning the Talent business to focus more on **customer**
> **employer branding** and company awareness needs, and moving away from
> job slots and direct hiring. This will tie the product closer to what
> we offer through Stack Overflow Advertising...

### Curious about "Customer Employer Branding"?

I am! Staffer and moderator Puneet Mulchandani recommends a link to ***Academy to Innovate HR*** (AIHR) with whom Stack Overflow will presumably be consulting or partnering as it sunsets Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story. The URL in Puneet's question/announcement links to [Stack Overflow Advertising Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/solutions), and this depiction of Prashanth's plan to focus more on customer needs.

> [image: Advertising Solutions on Stack Overflow with with Audio Bubble]

### The scent of [Goldman Sachs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldman_Sachs)

Give users and advertisers some time to adjust. I'm certain that members of our little network of SE knowledge reuse communities will benefit, as well as corporate entities such as Goldman Sachs (the latter was mentioned in the article linked to by Puneet) from AIHR's ["How to Build a Successful Employer Branding Strategy for Your Business"](https://www.aihr.com/blog/employer-branding-strategy/):

> employer brand is “your unique scent as a company”

which informs that

> to build a successful employer brand, you want to be targeting as many
> relevant channels as possible to communicate your message. This
> includes your careers page, as well as social media channels like Twitter,
> Instagram, or even TikTok.

Goldman Sachs will discover TikTok to be a fine source of [OCaml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective_Caml) and [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) developers no doubt. Everyone, be they Stack Overflow teams or site users will derive  value from this AIHR embedded chart!

> [image: AIHR diagram]

Comment: _"It is unfortunate that the CEO of StackExchange has concluded that"_ Who says the CEO came to that conclusion? For the rest, this answer is pretty much all over the place... What are you saying here?

Comment: @Cerbrus You are correct. OP Puneet M. made the observation that I attributed to the CEO of StackExchange. I will correct that misattribution now. Thank you for bringing it to my attention!

Comment: *[A damn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4EsqvYBeyws)* *[good diagram!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KxwcQ1dapw8&t=20s)*

Comment: Thank you, @PeterMortensen! Your additions of inline URLs significantly improved my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If there are a few volunteers I will be happy to work with them to develop a new site that works exactly like SO Job and SO Developer story. We could start with SO developer story because personally I can't miss this feature! it's not possible.

Comment: Re *"If there are a few volunteers I will be happy to work with them"*: [Para D expressed a similar thought](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story/415854#415854) (near *"build something yourself and open it to the world"*)

Comment: I like the idea! I don't know how much I can promise, but I am always up for reviewing stuff. Can you organise something?

Comment: I started working on the project. The first feature is to generate a resume quickly. Back-end and DevOps sides are almost Ok. If you're interested in contributing to the project just let me know. Actually, the help of a front-end (reactjs preferred) dev will really be welcome but you can also join if you're a developer,devOps, designer or QA.

Answer (score 3):

Sad to see these features go. It was useful to have a beat on the current job market while I worked on my projects. Organically using SO activity as part of a portfolio was also useful.

Answer (score 3):

Good decision.

Jobs for me weren't much different from [LinkedIn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn).
It is not a place where I actively look for a job, rather another venue for recruiters to find me. It's enough work to keep one job profile up to date and for me that will be LinkedIn as basically the most popular and flexible one.

I wasn't applying for a job myself in a long time. Usually I just respond to recruiters' messages when I'm interested. For me it doesn't really matter if I respond to an invite from recruiter finding me on LinkedIn or on SO.

SO should focus on its community and basic features. I don't ask questions frequently here, but when I browse new questions looking for a possibility to help or just looking for an answer myself, I can see that most of them has comments screaming at the person who posted the question to use search instead of adding a question and generally calling for a moderator.

This brings to mind old times of [phpBB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpBB) fora where almost every new topic met pretty much the same response screaming for a moderator as someone who doesn't have better things to do and knows literally every topic in the forum happened to see a similar question and decided to subdue a newcomer.

There is a lot to be done to make SO more newbie friendly and focusing on a job board feature for sure wasn't the way to get there.

Comment: It's pretty clear what we're losing now. But a SO team that's more focused on its area of expertise is going to bring a ton of value in the long-term. Removing a widely-used features isn't ideal, but I agree that this could be a good decision.

Comment: Re *"make SO more newbie friendly"*: It is long overdue, and a change of tone is not sufficient. Jeff Atwood [supports it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jurlnqqWKA&t=43m32s): *"There needs to be a beginner version of Stack Overflow."*. One of the better received proposals is *[Create a separate, independent advanced Stack Overflow, focusing on being a knowledge library (but still part of the network)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983)*.

Answer (score 3):

I am set for some time in my current role, but I can tell you in the past answers and presence on SO have helped me get attention from prospective employers and even get hired.  In my mind SO + GitHub + LinkedIn are three essential pieces to develop to showcase one's talent, although the first two show quality of one's work.  So having SO not directly as part of one's job experience will be a big miss for so many.

Answer (score 3):

The point of differentiation to me about SO Jobs was that it was developer-focused - as is the rest of SO - rather than employer focused - like all the other job sites out there.

I understand that B2B is an easier model, and B2C is not too hard either, and I can even see that C2B is an almost impossible ask.  Perhaps this policy change now indicates that it is, after all, an impossible task.

C'est la vie :-(

Answer (score 3):

Is there a new feature that Stack Overflow will be pouring their resources into once the Jobs and Developer Story portions of the platform have been discontinued? I'd like to see new and significant development to enhance the question-answer forums on SO if this side of the business is going away for good.

Answer (score 3):

I realize that I’m a little late to the party but I just wanted to say that SO’s job board was the only place that I felt like developers were posting jobs for other developers. I found 3 jobs there that altered the trajectory of my career in amazing ways and I didn’t have to wade through a bunch of “cold call” emails from recruiters about “positions I’d be a great fit for” which are clearly not a great fit. I realize that sometimes things we like must be sacrificed for the greater good, but this seems like a short sighted decision made by a bunch of C Level types that makes sense on paper when it comes to the bottom line, but not when considering the community you serve. It would be wonderful to see the board come back some day, even if it was a toned down version.

Answer (score 2):

This was the only place to find quality job listings.  That came from the community.  No special features or development required.  It's a let down for sure.

Comment: Eh, I dunno about that one...

Comment: Trying to kill my community love Makoto?

Comment: i mean, love teh community all you want, that's not gonna prevent people (of said community or otherwise) from disagreeing with you.

Comment: @jinnjus - if it dies from literally one skeptical comment, you can't say it was particularly strong to begin with...

Comment: OK, fine I don't get it.  Where's the problem?  You have a job board for developers attached to the internet's goto documentation for developers and you need some extra shiny baubles also?  Clarify your comment.  This is stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

SO Jobs is my go-to place to look for jobs. I love that it automatically sorts jobs according to my skills, which SO infers from the questions that I ask and answer. It is the place where I get the most accurate job offers. Also, the job search filters are the best. It is by far the best place to find jobs as a developer. Whoever convinced SO that they don't have strength in this market, was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another company's good ideas get killed off after it is acquired by another company.  So sad.

Answer (score 2):

Really sad to see the CV feature disappear, as it was a valuable resource for me (and probably many other) when applying for jobs.

One thing worries me though. There is this section that allows you to indicate your position in percentage among all users in different tags:

[image: user stats]

Unfortunately I couldn't find any other place on the site where I could retrieve these vital statistics when looking for jobs. Is it possible to have these statistics officially displayed on another page of the site?

Comment: Someone should take this idea and turn it into an actionable feature request.

Comment: @KevinB Any idea how I can have more impact to make it possible?

Comment: The best way would be to create a feature request, by asking a new question with the feature request tag, suggesting how how the profile page can be changed to include this information… such as adding a “Top n%” for each tag in the list of tag badges you have

Comment: I created a project called [stackoverflow-readme-profile](https://stackoverflow-readme-profile.vercel.app/) that enable you to get your ranking for a specific tag and share a dynamic badge on your website/README.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked the developer story. It’s too bad that will be going. It was a fresh take on a resume and could be exported right into a resume. It doesn’t seem like it would take much to keep and with minimal work, could have been technical market competitor for LinkedIn.

Answer (score 2):

As a developer and a person who have used Stack Overflow jobs, I think it appears pretty much that people who are us and we are your customers your users totally disagree with such a decision.
One of the most important things in any business is to always see what customers want and listen to their feedback.

Then why remove something the users need so, much I think Stack Overflow jobs have a really important place in our job search with no similar alternatives many jobs that exist on it do not exist on LinkedIn or many other famous websites.
I think you need to rethink this.

And if this part of Stack Overflow is a big burden then why not try to open source it. We as a community of developers at least can try and maintain it since it is something important to us give us the chance to help support it.

Comment: You are not SE's customer, you are the product.

Answer (score 2):

Like for a lot of developers, I've maintained my career history on Developer Story for some years as a primary source for my CV. I found its format to be much more relevant than tools available elsewhere which are not specific to developers. Hugely disappointed that it is being removed.

Answer (score 2):

I would say discontinuing *Jobs* is a bad decision. Stack Overflow Jobs always provided high quality and good results apart from other job platforms. I am very  disappointed realizing *Jobs* is no more.

Answer (score 2):

It’s very sad to see the Stack Overflow Jobs being terminated. It used to be one of the major and reliable source of job listings for people looking for remote jobs or jobs across nations.

I really wish the leaders see the impact *Jobs* made to a lot of people,
#bringbackstackoverflowjobs  :(

Answer (score 2):

Your overindulgence in third party cookie policy was disincentivising me as it was.
Now you've taken away the incentive to want to help others.

As much as it is nice to help others answer question, helping and boosting your stats was a way to show you knew your stuff to potential employees.

Bad call. Not impressed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still mourning the loss of Stack Overflow Jobs.

I still can't believe you let go of the best job board for developers.

It was not only a place to find jobs. It was a place to feel cared, appreciated. Just browsing at jobs there gave a sense of hope for the future. It was a job board that truly put developers first, a place that really understood what developers want.

Don't think that you (SO leadership) make SO. You don't make SO. You just enable a place for developers to make SO. Developers make this every day by sharing knowledge and also by daring to ask. You are the stewards. I sincerely hope that you can understand what this means.

Answer (score 2):

SO reached a new low. I don't understand *any* of the decisions that were taken lately. Could it get any worse?

Answer (score 2):

I'm really sad for this choice. I used to update my developer story and to download it like a CV to share.

This post does not want to be a criticism for the closure, but the sharing of a micro project: I am not a LaTeX guru, but I have largely reproduced the [style of the CV](https://github.com/bilardi/stackoverflow-cv) that could be downloaded from Stack Overflow and also created a version with something more.

If you want to contribute, you can create a pull request.

I hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

The reasoning they give for shutting down SO Jobs is truly baffling and contradicting to the actual state of SO Jobs.

SO Jobs was leagues ahead of other job sites as it was, both in community and features for the SO Jobs itself. There was not a single other job hunting site where displaying a salary range was the norm. The filters for job hunting here were much more advanced than any site, like LinkedIn.

Furthermore, the community for this job hosting site was in a league of its own; where accounts could be tied with real contributions to the programming world. Who else could do that? No one. Did I mention that SO Jobs didn’t have recruiters spamming your inbox?

**Putting the pieces together**

So, SO Jobs was the top of its class and already had the features to run on its own. Even were they to stop development and spend minimal time on upkeep, the application would run fine more or less. Searching 'Top Programmer Job sites' would almost always reveal SO Jobs in their list. This alone discredits a lot of the OPs original reasoning.

**Conclusion**

This leads me to believe that there was some foul play afoot in Stack Overflow. Either you or a higher up was paid by a company like LinkedIn to shut down your self-running service so another company could gain a more competitive advantage in the industry. If this ends up being just a conspiracy theory from me then I don't have any other option but to believe there was some huge flaws in the software itself, or the people making the decision on this site have no overview on the Job Hunting market for programmers.

The reasoning you give simply doesn't add up to any logical conclusion, and it is probably a big reason why this is one of the most downvoted SO 'questions' in SO history.

Answer (score 2):

I really loved SO jobs; I got many interesting proposals from employers and almost moved to another country due to this.

This platform was really useful for foreigners trying to get a better job in another country. For example, I were able to search if I wanted a 100% remote job or not, look up for job offers in a specific country, per salary, expertise (junior, midlevel, senior) or if visa sponsorship was offered or not. Also, it was a cool place to discover different companies around the world.

To be honest, this easy-to-use/simple platform was even better than LinkedIn and others (I really liked the search criteria that I could use).

I wish it comes back at some point or another!

Answer (score 2):

> Developers, as you all know, don’t have a hard time finding job opportunities.

This statement aged like milk. Developers do have a hard time finding a job in 2023, especially juniors.

Answer (score 1):

I must say, I'm sad to see this go. While I haven't been looking for a job for quite awhile, it was helpful to have what people are hiring for readily visible to me as job ads; it made it easier for me to ensure that I wasn't missing some new skill that I should know about and that my salary is "on target" with the rest of the market.

Answer (score 1):

Sad news, as you are taking off a useful tool.

On the other hand, I can hardly realize how can you think of employer branding in such an atomized environment.

Answer (score 1):

Dropping SO Jobs to focus and support "Employer Branding" (read advertising, wait... the post straight up called it Advertising) is just wrong IMO.

Just like any other advertising, those with the money will get more exposure, and thus the "big tech" can scalp for jobs. It's the little tech that is often the better job. And browsing SO Jobs was just so much easier than sites like [Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeed) or [ZipRecruiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZipRecruiter). A posting on SO Jobs felt like the employer actually knew what tech was, and what they actually needed, instead of an entry level Java posting requiring 15 years experience.

And this brings up another question. If the Salary Calculator is going away, are all the salary questions on the annual developer survey also going away? Is the survey itself going away? I'd rather know about the jobs and where/how developers/IT are working. If there is no more SO Jobs, there's no need for the survey. Honestly, I really don't care what percentage of us use [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) or [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs), or what game you all are playing.

I don't bother answering questions anymore because of the "[fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533)" issue. Now I won't even be able to browse jobs on here. I'll still frequent the rest of Stack Exchange, but I might be done with SO for now.

Not to mention [the controversy with Monica Cellio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFiQPkdb5Qs), Shog9 leaving, Joel making political posts, and the licensing changes.

Answer (score 1):

I used the developer story(traditional way) as the resume and got the current job.

It's really a sad story for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's sad to see that SO is sunsetting the job board. As a developer I really liked SO jobs. The success rate of getting calls from company on SO was way higher than the LinkedIn.

Good thing about company profile in SO was that I can check who other SO user is working for that company.

Anyway I will miss the job board.

Answer (score 1):

#1 Could you at least keep the rest api of the developer history feature?

#2 You said:

> The effort it would take us to truly differentiate in this space is not one we could justify.

Maybe you could be a complement to work for the developer welfare, not necessarily a competitor.

Answer (score 1):

The best would have been to have the community vote. Indeed, if I don't really use the "job search" part, the developer story, on the other hand, was the basis of my CV and helped me in my research, if only to remember a project to show.

Does anyone know of a website/platform that offers a free developer storytelling solution? If not, are any of you interested in setting up such a site?

Comment: So far, I know of https://developerstory.dev/story/vonc and https://devstory.fyi/vonc

Comment: More info on **DevStory** in this [StackApps post](https://stackapps.com/questions/9354/export-so-developer-story-to-devstory-fyi) as well.

Comment: Also: https://www.getmanfred.com/profile/vonc

Answer (score 1):

It is really sad to see it going. But I think in some ways, it has also taken away some of the credibility that I put on my website to prove my tech skills to the recruiters. It was really motivating to see if I was shown as *1% for Angular* contribution.

I am not sure if that is even possible, but at least the developer link that you created was a nice support from SO to its contributors. I added my [Pluralsight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluralsight) scores which I completed with one of my previous companies' email address. Now with SO developer portal gone and me switched the company, I lost what I built over last three years on SO to showcase my skill.

I think this should have also been communicated more clearly to all developers (just like you pull the attention to the developer survey when you needed it). I was away from SO for a few months now and it is all lost. SO disappointed me deeply. With this drastic change, I am not sure, in the future, if I would actually cherish my SO profile anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why not turn it into a paid feature instead of dropping it altogether ? Like every other app does, one could choose between a free account, with access to the QA side of things only, and a premium account with access to the jobs stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you spin it off? Then you wouldn't invite the ire of the community. Because somebody is going to provide the functionality that you removed. And the business who treats the customer right—is the one who gets the customer. A local restaurant has a poster on the wall that has a lot of wisdom to it:

- It takes a lot of investment and time to win a customer.
- It only takes seconds to lose them.

May your replacement arise quickly. And beat your pants off.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the decision. The market has certainly changed in the last 10 years and in retrospect I never much used the job board directly, but at least the positive takeaway is that the market is in our favour as developers. It's never been easier to find gainful employment!

That being said, it is sad to see Developer Stories go. Like many, I haven't bothered maintaining a resume for the last decade because Stack Overflow was so convenient. To that end, I've looked to replicate the PDF format through a theme for the [JSON Resume](https://jsonresume.org/) CLI tool.

If anyone is feeling bereft of this feature, hopefully this will be of some use:

- https://github.com/mylesj/jsonresume-theme-stackoverflowed

Answer (score 0):

### An incredibly terrible decision, I am dumbfounded!

Answer (score -2):

1. Feature maintaining price is zero.
2. Profit from removing the feature is zero.
3. Informing on upcoming changes is poor. No warning anywhere.
4. Discussion is low (see p.3). No voting.
5. Time before cutoff is short.

Decision looks like some product of manager games. Illogical, made on the quiet and hurriedly decision.

Comment: 1: Hosting price is non-zero. Employees responsible of maintaining jobs (content & code) aren't free. 4: this is not a democracy.

Answer (score -2):

Shortly after StackOverflow Jobs shut down on March 31, 2022, the software job market nosedived. It still hasn't recovered as of August 2023. (And it might never recover, now that remote work is widespread and ChatGPT exists.)

It seems they knew what was about to happen. Even in January, when they made this announcement.

Answer (score -4):

Wow! This is not so good, but if you must, instead of destroying it, why not move it elsewhere?

This is one of the reasons I don't like third-party stuff. Third party is always use at your own risk. They can yank you off whenever they like and you must obey their rules.

It’s your problem...we move.

Comment: What are you talking about? E.g., what is an example of a third party that does this? Move where?

Comment: Mr. take a chill pill and relax......You should be answering that question if SO is the only one that offers Jobs feature, google has it too FYI. so whats the big deal here?

Comment: "Move it elsewhere" makes no sense, when the entire point of it was it was connected to your SO profile, which is here, not elsewhere. There is no moving it elsewhere.

Comment: OK, but don't say "makes no sense" to other people's suggestion, it's not nice.
SO made their decision already, so no point. They are not asking us, they are telling us.

Comment: I'm sorry you felt that wasn't nice? What way of saying you are wrong would have been nice?

Comment: if you want to know, remove "makes no sense" from your previous comment and see.

Answer (score -4):

i want to say something you cant do remove jobs section because its  very helpful is new software junior developer maybe you can remove it developer story but jobs is still need this community... thx Stackoverflow team! for create this communitiy.

Comment: Unfortunately they already seem to have made up their minds on this one.

Comment: "Stack Overflow", not "Stackoverflow". See e.g. *"[Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)"*.

Answer (score -7):

The Jobs and CV parts were good, but not best.

I hope to see Stack Overflow investing time on better things after sunsetting this common feature among all sites.

Keep it up, SO.