# Intro statement is missing in the Developer Story PDF export

Tags: bug, developer-story

I just tried to save my developer story as a PDF before the whole feature is removed.

Unfortunately, the intro statement is completely missing in the PDF.
Could you add it to the PDF export?

Comment: Related: [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293)

Comment: I know it‘s going away. I want to fully export it *before* it goes away, and I‘d like the intro statement included in the export.

Comment: @ChristianSpecht I've put together a JSON exporter for Developer Story which includes the intro statement. It's not a PDF export, but at least you'll get a copy of all your data before it goes away: https://developerstory.dev/stackoverflow

Comment: @ChristianSpecht does export allows you to see the % top percents? In my case those are not exported as well...

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos: no, the top % are missing in my export as well.

Comment: ...and they have already changed the HTML version. Right now, it isn't editable anymore, and my intro statement is missing there as well. Apparently the current HTML version was generated by the same thing that does the PDF export.