# Job link on tag page 404s

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, stack-overflow-jobs

Tags that have jobs associated with them have a "[tag] jobs" link on them:

[image: "javascript jobs"]

Since [Jobs is no more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293/10113238), this link now 404s. It should be removed.

Comment: We can reproduce this, updated build going out in a little bit with a few other fixes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing out that issue! We have fixed it and the fix has been deployed to production. The jobs tag will no longer show.