# Developer Story was discontinued, but I didn't know. Can I still get it?

Tags: support, developer-story

I just found out five days too late that the developer story feature is gone -
*[Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story)*

Is there still a way I can export my data (for the developer story)?

Comment: You could try a GDPR data request, although if they've already removed the data from their systems, I'd expect that not to work either.

Comment: Didn't they send out an email about it some weeks or months ago?

Comment: A GDPR data request doesn't contain the developer story, @Nick. It does contain that data, but not formatted in any useful way, last I checked.

Comment: When removing much-loved features, might I suggest, a rolling blackout with increasing periods, over several months ;-D

Comment: Just did the same journey. I'd like to further suggest that since it's for Developers: just email everyone with a full JSON export as a part of the sunsetting. I put a lot of time in to the copywriting and it's simply gone. It does not feel good.

Comment: Was there a database dump from the time we could look at, before the feature got removed?

Answer (score 16):

If you wanted to save the information, the export (either copy-paste, screenshot, or via external tools) had to be done before the removal of the Developer Story.

Since the Developer Story page is removed/no longer public, all the [external tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bdeveloper-story%5D+export+is%3Aa+url%3A%22http%22&mixed=0) created by the community can no longer access this information, and therefore cannot assist with exporting any longer.

It also appears that the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org) did not archive everyone's developer stories because the path was excluded for some reason.

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

Good news—even though it was excluded from the Wayback Machine for some reason, it's still in the Google Cache! (Or at least mine is.) Simply search Google for `cache:https://stackoverflow.com/cv/<your-username>`, for example I searched for `cache:https://stackoverflow.com/cv/laughinghan`

Comment: Nice, didn't work for mine tho, I must be not popular enough ;-)

Comment: @myster Did you see AndrzejStencel's answer? You can try searching on google for the URL and if you're lucky maybe you got the URL slightly wrong

Comment: I did try that but it didn't work for me. Also, yours is no-longer in the google cache.

Comment: @Myster :'( sad (luckily I saved a PDF)

Answer (score 2):

Try pasting your Jobs profile URL in Google and retrieving the cached version.

- Type `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/<jobs-profile-name>` in Google Search. Note that your Jobs profile name might be different from your Stack Overflow profile name, in my case it was `andrzejstencel` vs. `andrzej-stencel`. The URL for the search was for me: https://www.google.com/search?q=https%253A%252F%252Fstackoverflow.com%252Fcv%252Fandrzejstencel
- If you get a result, click on the three dots to the right and then click the "Cached" pill at the bottom of the pop-up. If it's not there, I guess you're out of luck and your profile hasn't been cached.

This is what it looked like for me on April 27th, 2022:[image: google-search-result]

My cached cv: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:PQPVzYa8lagJ:https://stackoverflow.com/cv/andrzejstencel+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in

Comment: Using Google Cache was already suggested in another answer, in a more convenient way. (You can just search directly with `cache:` and don't need to use the search UI itself).

Comment: Of course I checked the other answer first, but it didn't work for me. I wanted to comment on that answer, but don't have enough reputation, so taht's why I created a new answer that worked for me.

Comment: Oh, I think I know why that answer didn't work for me - it's because the profile name was off. `cache:https://stackoverflow.com/cv/andrzej-stencel` gives me a 404, but searching for `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/andrzej-stencel` in Google UI returned the correct `https://stackoverflow.com/cv/andrzejstencel` result. This means my answer can hopefully be useful for people who don't know their exact profile name. I agree a comment on that answer would be better that a whole separate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work for me, I guess google hadn't cached mine. also @Andrezej's is no-longer in the google cache.