# White text color on white background in companies filter search bar

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

On the "[Best Companies hiring developers](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies)" page, when I was adding tags to filter the companies, I noticed that when a dark theme is selected the colour of the text and filter-search bar both are white. I am attaching screenshots of my finding below:

- **When the theme is white it works normally.**
  [image: With white theme]
- **When the theme is dark:**
  [image: When the theme is dark]

  [image: when text is selected]

---

Note that this is not answered/addressed by [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293), as this page is not part of Jobs or Developer Story. That post specifically notes that the company pages section of the site is **not** being sunset (emphasis mine):

> Companies can continue to use Stack Overflow’s Employer Branding solutions to promote their employer brand **through company pages** and other types of advertising.