# Add link to "Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story" from the 404 page for Jobs

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, 404-not-found

Currently, when visiting old SO Job URLs (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/jobs), the visitor will be redirected to the 404 page which says:

> ### Page not found
>
> #### Oh no! We can't find the page you're looking for.
>
> Here are some helpful links instead.
>
> - [Search companies](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies)
>
> If you think we've made an error, please [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Except... for most people who missed the announcement of [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story), they will be more confused since they are looking for *jobs*, not *companies*.

Thus, the request is simple: add [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story) as the first entry on the list, making it:

> - [Sunsetting Jobs & Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story)
> - [Search companies](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies)

Comment: There is precedent for adding a page. Something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/documentation would be ideal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've got a PR to introduce a memorial page for Jobs and Dev Story just like we do for Documentation; I'll be merging it next week

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A memorial page for Jobs and Developer Stories was definitely a good idea in retrospect. We were so focused on making sure things didn't break as we shutdown the product that we forgot to make a memorial for its links and thought the previous 404 page was enough. Our bad!

Anyways, I've added the memorial page for Jobs and Developer Stories with links to the respective Meta post so hopefully it'll be clearer to future users.