# Search company by technology is broken?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, companies-page

When I search the company by technology, e.g. if I click the button "python"

[image: python]

I was directed to a broken link https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/developer-jobs-using-python

The same with any other technology. But I was surprised to find no one report it.

Comment: While the proposed dupe is useful, looks like it's a valid bug report that the dev may have forgotten to fix/add a feature to filter companies by tags, instead of pointing to the deprecated jobs.

Comment: Not at all. I know sunsetting job but I was talking about a broken link in its replacement.

Comment: Why does "Companies" (/jobs/companies) even still exist, now that Jobs has been officially removed? Seems like the removal of Jobs is incomplete.

Comment: @CodyGray Seems like they intended to continue that part of the jobs pages, see ["Companies can continue to use Stack Overflow’s Employer Branding solutions to promote their employer brand through company pages and other types of advertising"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story).

Comment: Oh, I see, @Tom. *Of course* the blatant advertising is still there, but not the parts that would actually be useful to either the companies *or* the users. Well, no wonder no one has ever noticed/reported this bug before. :-)

Comment: Apparently, there is already a feature to filter companies by tags by using the top-right button "Filter by tag", where it will redirect to a working link `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?tl=list+of+tags`.

Comment: @CodyGray Are you suggesting I am really the first one to report it?! Man, I have noticed this problem for some times.

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes I noticed that but actually that one doesn't quite work too.

Comment: @Qiulang maybe yes, maybe no. The company list can only show a limited amount of tags. Check the company detail instead, they may have more tags than what is shown.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for reporting this bug! We've updated the tags so that when clicked, they now link to the company search page with that technology filter applied.

Comment: This actually introduces another problem with filter I also noticed for a while: when I filter a technology, say python, it indeed filters out the companies using python but the problem is that company may list many technologies in their stack and python is not their top 3, so the result seems a bit confusing, e.g. filter python will show https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/creative-assembly who list c++ as  their top 3 tech stack.

Comment: @Qiulang I guess that's a different issue altogether. You might want to post a new feature request to discuss which approach is preferred: filtering only from the top 3 or filtering from all tags.