# Unable to remove excluded company

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

A long time ago I added one company to the "Companies to exclude" section in my preferences. However, I believe excluded companies were only relevant when jobs and developer story was around. Now that it's been [sunsetted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story), I don't think it's necessary to keep excluded companies (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So I tried to remove the company in order to declutter the preferences page, but clicking on the X doesn't do anything. There is also no console error or network request. See the below gif for a demonstration.

Apart from fixing the x button not working, if the "Companies to exclude" section is not used anymore, can it be removed?

[image: Nothing happens when clicking on the X to remove a company]

Comment: The code behind that x is already sunsetted  ...

Comment: @rene perhaps the whole companies to exclude section needs to be removed.

Comment: Yeah. It is probably hard to remove all features at once when you no longer offer the functionality the feature was meant for.

Comment: all at once???, this switch was long time ago

Comment: I'm picking up this bug in this sprint; in terms of the purpose of this feature, it is still used to hide companies and their respective updates (in any hypothetical future UI) from https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, the code that handled the "X" and company search was coupled together with Dev Story code. So when we removed the Dev Story code, this company search functionality was also broken. Why they were coupled together? I'm not sure!

Anyways, here's the cleaned up version that is functional and no longer has oversized company logos!

[image: Preview of the revised "Companies to exclude" section of user preferences]