What is the motivation to use Stack Overflow Jobs over just using Indeed?
It seems that Stack Overflow Jobs is just a simplified version of Indeed, right?
It seems like it would make more sense to just go to Indeed and get the same thing but with more functionality.
Not trying to express negative feeling towards it, but genuinely wondering what the point is. I was under the impression that Indeed wasn't the hottest site for devs as is; this seems like it's making it worse.

None. It's a giant advert for indeed with some SO branding, and nothing more.

genuinely wondering what the point is. I assume there is a money flow from Indeed towards SO. Bills need to be paid.

from a user standpoint, we'd be better served by the link instead just linking to indeed. as it stands it is useless for anyone not looking for a job specific to a city... and even then you can't be sure you're looking at the correct city.

@Zoe careful the overlords see all, your SO account will puff ... I for one welcome our new overlords

I remember when the old jobs/dev-story was shutdown, a lot of us downvoted that: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story ... while the new "replacement" is crappy now, we can only hope they will bring back the best of the old version into this new stuff

I'd probably view it as an "affiliate link" type of situation, where we'd be supporting SE getting a few pennies by using it.  If, however as you say, it's less functional than just going to Indeed, then that might not make as much sense.

@HelderSepulveda I'm guessing that the staff costs of maintaining that system were greater than the revenue obtained from it.  That doesn't seem likely to change.

@NotTheDr01ds "the staff costs of maintaining that system", if you have inside info please share with the rest of the class ... software is the least staff expensive business, on this case all you need is a few DB tables, some APIs and a frontend, all (or most) the R/D was already done, there was no need to completely turn off that feature entirely, maybe set it autopilot and no more enhancements or bug fixes, it upset a lot of developers you can see it in that thread

@HelderSepulveda erm, you seem to be the one who seems to have the inside knowledge of how much SE had to pay in terms of time and effort maintaining the product...

"...it's making it worse..." I agree with everything else but here I'm not sure. Does it really make it worse? I could imaging that SO Indeed maybe only cuts the boring stuff away from Indeed and then it wouldn't matter where you go.

@HelderSepulveda I'm just going on an assumption based on how most business decisions are made.  I was also considering the head-count cost of selling these jobs ads.  I don't know whether or not there was some "affiliate" type of passthrough with the old system - I figured that since it was bespoke, that it might involve more direct sales involvement, which didn't pay for itself.  Again, all conjecture.  I just doubt that the old system will return, since I also assume that the situations that led to its removal haven't been resolved.

@VLAZ maybe some inside knowledge... but I would call it "outside" knowledge from my many years of building software, there is a lot of stuff out there that was built in languages that are no longer supported but still run... maybe I liked the old jobs and developer story too much, to me there was nothing like it competing with it.

Relevant: In the future we hope to build out more unique functionality...

Given the big and prominent "powered by indeed" label at the top of the page and the lack of a StackOverflow-specific candidate profile, I guess this is just a paid collaboration (similarly to those with Google and OpenAI), so the motivation is probably money, not to help the community.
In the post about the sunsetting of the old Jobs, which got a lot of downvotes and negative feedback from the community, it was already evident that a reason, or the reason, for the sunsetting of Jobs was money, or lack thereof (bold is mine):

Why?
[...]
While Talent & Jobs helped us get to where we are over the past decade, the talent acquisition space is not one where we have a strong competitive advantage. Developers, as you all know, don’t have a hard time finding job opportunities. The problem is often finding the right opportunity and job boards and sourcing are ineffective solutions. The effort it would take us to truly differentiate in this space is not one we could justify.

— I guess they are referring to financial effort here.
Also, this new Jobs doesn't seem to do anything remotely similar to the old Jobs:

Huge list of low-quality job posts, rather than a smaller and highly curated list of quality jobs and companies.

No job recommendations based on your activity and preferences on StackOverflow, such as "Watched Tags".

Requires you to create an Indeed account rather than using your StackOverflow one. Also, Indeed has no integration with your StackOverflow profile. It's exactly the same as navigating to Indeed on your own and creating a new account.

Given the lack of a proper integration, this probably has no advantage for the candidate either. With the old Jobs, your StackOverflow answers could be used to highlight your knowledge about certain technologies and/or make it stand out.



As an employer: The benefit of the infamously sunsetted Jobs was the ability to clearly tag jobs, same as questions, and immediately recognize good applicants by their content.
As an employee: The benefit of the infamously sunsetted Jobs was the ability to search for clearly tagged jobs, same as questions, and immediately recognize relevant employers by their posting.

That being said, I don't see any benefit of the new Jobs.

Indeed is among the worst sites for looking for tech jobs, so it's surprising that they would partner with them.  The biggest useability barrier is they don't handle a number of tech/programming-language keywords properly.  If you search for C#, results are polluted with C/C++ postings and vice versa (and not a case of they mention C# in body, you can look an see C# is no where in the posting).  It's pretty easy to configure something like Lucene to properly handle C# versus C++ and not return results that don't include one or another. IMO going through and enumerating domain specific phrases to be handled properly is pretty important if you run a targeted search engine.
